# Permutations/Anagrams in Objective-C -- I am missing something

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sdk, permutation

(code below regarding my question)

Per [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791265/generating-permutations-of-nsarray-elements) I used Pegolon's approach to generating all possible permutations of a group of characters inside an NSString.  However, I am now trying to get it to not just generate an ANAGRAM which is all permutations of the same length, but all possible combinations (any length) of the characters in a string.

Would anyone know how i would alter the following code to get it to do this?  This is much like: [Generate All Permutations of All Lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074991/generate-all-permutations-of-all-lengths) -- but (for fear of them needing answer to homework) they did not leave code.  I have a sample of what I thought would do it at the bottom of this post... but it did not.

So, the code, as is, generates `the`, `teh`, `hte`, `het`, `eth` and `eht` when given `THE`.
What I need is along the lines of: `t`,`h`,`e`,`th`,`ht`,`te`,`he` (etc) in addition to the above 3 character combinations.

How would I change this, please.  (ps: There are two methods in this.  I added `allPermutationsArrayofStrings` in order to get the results back as strings, like I want them, not just an array of characters in another array).  I am assuming the magic would happen in `pc_next_permutation` anyway -- but thought I would mention it.

In NSArray+Permutation.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSArray(Permutation)
- (NSArray *)allPermutationsArrayofArrays;
- (NSArray *)allPermutationsArrayofStrings;

@end
```

in NSArray+Permutation.m:

```
#define MAX_PERMUTATION_COUNT   20000

NSInteger *pc_next_permutation(NSInteger *perm, const NSInteger size);
NSInteger *pc_next_permutation(NSInteger *perm, const NSInteger size) 
{
    // slide down the array looking for where we're smaller than the next guy
    NSInteger pos1;
    for (pos1 = size - 1; perm[pos1] >= perm[pos1 + 1] && pos1 > -1; --pos1);

    // if this doesn't occur, we've finished our permutations
    // the array is reversed: (1, 2, 3, 4) => (4, 3, 2, 1)
    if (pos1 == -1)
        return NULL;

    assert(pos1 >= 0 && pos1 <= size);

    NSInteger pos2;
    // slide down the array looking for a bigger number than what we found before
    for (pos2 = size; perm[pos2] <= perm[pos1] && pos2 > 0; --pos2);

    assert(pos2 >= 0 && pos2 <= size);

    // swap them
    NSInteger tmp = perm[pos1]; perm[pos1] = perm[pos2]; perm[pos2] = tmp;

    // now reverse the elements in between by swapping the ends
    for (++pos1, pos2 = size; pos1 < pos2; ++pos1, --pos2) {
        assert(pos1 >= 0 && pos1 <= size);
        assert(pos2 >= 0 && pos2 <= size);

        tmp = perm[pos1]; perm[pos1] = perm[pos2]; perm[pos2] = tmp;
    }

    return perm;
}

@implementation NSArray(Permutation)

- (NSArray *)allPermutationsArrayofArrays
{
    NSInteger size = [self count];
    NSInteger *perm = malloc(size * sizeof(NSInteger));

    for (NSInteger idx = 0; idx < size; ++idx)
        perm[idx] = idx;

    NSInteger permutationCount = 0;

    --size;

    NSMutableArray *perms = [NSMutableArray array];

    do {
        NSMutableArray *newPerm = [NSMutableArray array];

        for (NSInteger i = 0; i <= size; ++i)
            [newPerm addObject:[self objectAtIndex:perm[i]]];

        [perms addObject:newPerm];
    } while ((perm = pc_next_permutation(perm, size)) && ++permutationCount < MAX_PERMUTATION_COUNT);
    free(perm);

    return perms;
}

- (NSArray *)allPermutationsArrayofStrings
{
    NSInteger size = [self count];
    NSInteger *perm = malloc(size * sizeof(NSInteger));

    for (NSInteger idx = 0; idx < size; ++idx)
        perm[idx] = idx;

    NSInteger permutationCount = 0;

    --size;

    NSMutableArray *perms = [NSMutableArray array];

    do {
        NSMutableString *newPerm = [[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"" ]autorelease];

        for (NSInteger i = 0; i <= size; ++i)
        {
            [newPerm appendString:[self objectAtIndex:perm[i]]];
        }
        [perms addObject:newPerm];
    } while ((perm = pc_next_permutation(perm, size)) && ++permutationCount < MAX_PERMUTATION_COUNT);
    free(perm);

    return perms;
}

@end
```

My code that I thought would fix this:

```
for ( NSInteger i = 1; i <= theCount; i++) {
                NSRange theRange2;
                theRange2.location = 0;
                theRange2.length = i;
                NSLog(@"Location: %i (len: %i) is: '%@'",theRange2.location,theRange2.length,[array subarrayWithRange:theRange2]);

                NSArray *allWordsForThisLength = [[array subarrayWithRange:theRange2] allPermutationsArrayofStrings];
                for (NSMutableString *theString in allWordsForThisLength)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Adding %@ as a possible word",theString);
                    [allWords addObject:theString];
                }
```

I know it would not be the most efficient..but I was trying to test.

This is what I got:

```
2011-07-07 14:02:19.684 TA[63623:207] Total letters in word: 3
2011-07-07 14:02:19.685 TA[63623:207] Location: 0 (len: 1) is: '(
    t
)'
2011-07-07 14:02:19.685 TA[63623:207] Adding t as a possible word
2011-07-07 14:02:19.686 TA[63623:207] Location: 0 (len: 2) is: '(
    t,
    h
)'
2011-07-07 14:02:19.686 TA[63623:207] Adding th as a possible word
2011-07-07 14:02:19.687 TA[63623:207] Adding ht as a possible word
2011-07-07 14:02:19.688 TA[63623:207] Location: 0 (len: 3) is: '(
    t,
    h,
    e
)'
2011-07-07 14:02:19.688 TA[63623:207] Adding the as a possible word
2011-07-07 14:02:19.689 TA[63623:207] Adding teh as a possible word
2011-07-07 14:02:19.690 TA[63623:207] Adding hte as a possible word
2011-07-07 14:02:19.691 TA[63623:207] Adding het as a possible word
2011-07-07 14:02:19.691 TA[63623:207] Adding eth as a possible word
2011-07-07 14:02:19.692 TA[63623:207] Adding eht as a possible word
```

As you can see, no one or two letter words -- I am pulling my hair out! (and I don't have much to spare!)

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please tag it as such so we know how best to help you.

Comment: No, this is not homework.  I almost wish it was.  Would indicate that I am much younger than I am... I am writing a program for IOS that needs this routine.

Comment: You do have a few one or two letter words. I see "t" and I see "th" and "ht"

Comment: I should've phrased that differently...What I meant to say was (in this case) you never see `HE`, cos before you ever get to the `E`, the `T` was already added to the word to be output... and thus you wont get a two letter word consisting of the third or later letter in the original word.  That is the best I can do to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy thing to do would be to take all subsets of size `k` and use the code you have to generate all permutations of the subset. This is easy, but not the most efficient.

---

Here's a better approach. You are generating permutations lexicographically in the first routine:

```
1234
1243
1324
1342
1423
...
```

Each time you call `NSInteger *pc_next_permutation(NSInteger *perm, const NSInteger size)`, you get the next permutation in lex order by finding the correct position to change. When you do that, truncate from the spot you changed to get the following:

```
1234 123 12 1
1243 124
1324 132 13
1342 134
1423 142 14
1432 143
2143 214 21 2
...
```

I hope the idea is clear. Here's one way to implement this (in Objective C-like pseudocode).

```
-(NSMutableArray *)nextPerms:(Perm *)word {
    int N = word.length;
    for (int i=N-1; i > 0; ++i) {
        if (word[i-1] < word[i]) {
            break;
        } else if (i==1) {
            i = 0;
        }
    }
    // At this point, i-1 is the leftmost position that will change
    if (i == 0) {
        return nil;
    }
    i = i-1;
    // At this point, i is the leftmost position that will change
    Perm *nextWord = word;
    for (int j=1; j <= N-i; ++j) {
        nextWord[i+j] = word[N-j];
    }
    nextWord[i] = nextWord[i+1];
    nextWord[i+1] = word[i];

    // At this point, nextPerm is the next permutation in lexicographic order.    

    NSMutableArray *permList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int j=i; j<N; ++j) {
        [permList addObject:[nextWord subwordWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,i)]];
    }
    return [permList autorelease];
}
```

This will return an array with the partial permutations as described above. The input for `nextPerms` should be the `lastObject` of the output of `nextPerms`.

Comment: not really.  because if you use THE as your word, the subset of size `K` would still only return results of size `K` with my code.  If I am wrong, please tell me.

Comment: @Jann: Yes, I propose doing this for k=1,2,...,N where N is the length of the string.

Comment: That is what my "addition" to the post indicated...that I tried to solve it :)  But, the problem is that it is not my original code so I am trying to understand it as well and am failing...which is why I am pulling my hair out.  I am not sure where in `pc_next_permutation` to do what you say.  It sounds like it would fix it but the problem for me is the "how".  Can you possibly give me a bit more help?

Comment: can you glance at the solution I came up with and see if it mirrors what you suggested?  If so, I will +1 and Check your answer...

Comment: @Jann: see my code above. This will give you the partial permutations I suggested. I didn't test this code, so my syntax and memory management may be off, but this should give you an idea of how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

Okay,

Down and dirty for now, however, this is what I did...

I changed the `NSArray+Permutations.m` to be as follows:

```
- (NSArray *)allPermutationsArrayofStrings
{
    NSInteger size = [self count];
    NSInteger *perm = malloc(size * sizeof(NSInteger));

    for (NSInteger idx = 0; idx < size; ++idx)
        perm[idx] = idx;

    NSInteger permutationCount = 0;

    --size;

    NSMutableArray *perms = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableDictionary *permsDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    do {
        NSMutableString *newPerm = [[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"" ]autorelease];

        for (NSInteger i = 0; i <= size; ++i)
        {
            [newPerm appendString:[self objectAtIndex:perm[i]]];
        }

        if ([permsDict objectForKey:newPerm] == nil)
        {
            [permsDict setObject:@"1" forKey:newPerm];
            [perms addObject:newPerm];
        }

        for (NSInteger i = 1; i <= [newPerm length]; ++i)
        {
            NSRange theRange;
            theRange.location = 0;
            theRange.length = i;
            if ([permsDict objectForKey:[newPerm substringToIndex:i]] ==  nil)
            {
                [permsDict setObject:@"1" forKey:[newPerm substringToIndex:i]];
                [perms addObject:[newPerm substringToIndex:i]];
            }
        }

    } while ((perm = pc_next_permutation(perm, size)) && ++permutationCount < MAX_PERMUTATION_COUNT);
    free(perm);

    [permsDict release];

    return perms;
}
```

The major changes were the idea @PengOne had...  Return the resulting lexically changed string but also shorten it by 1 character at a time and add that to the returned array if it did not exist already.

I chose to be "cheap" about it and keep track using a `NSMutableDictionary`.  So if the lexically changed string was not listed in the dictionary, it was added.

Is that more-or-less what you thought I should do, @PengOne?

WAY faster than adding them all and dealing with the resulting duplicates later -- and I think it works like I need it to.

Comment: More or less. The approach in my (newly added) code will avoid repetition entirely, so that will save a bit of time.