# How to generate all available permutations of NSArray elements

Tags: iphone

friends and sirs...

If I have an NSArray of NSNumbers like this: 1, 2, 3

Then the set of all possible permutations would look something like this:

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   1 , 2
>   1 , 3
>   2 , 3
>   2 , 1
>   3 , 1
>   3 , 2
>   1 , 2 , 3
>   1 , 3 , 2
>   2 , 1 , 3
>   ...

What's a good way to do this in XCode?

Please help me...

thanks.

Comment: I tried followings. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617253/permutations-anagrams-in-objective-c-i-am-missing-something but no luck....

Comment: Mathematically speaking, your example is not the permutations. A permutation is an organization of a set of objects in a particular order. To get a permutation of 1, 2, and 3, you need to use the objects 1, 2, and 3. 1 by itself is not a permutation of that set. 1 is a subset of the set.

Comment: Looks like a school assignment, that you haven't even given a shot at.