# How can I get all the possibles combinations of numbers from an array in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating permutations of NSArray elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791265/generating-permutations-of-nsarray-elements)

Let's say that I have

```
[1,2]
```

And I want to get

```
{1}
{2}
{1, 2}
{2, 3}
```

Comment: Where does `{2, 3}` come from?

Comment: Look up "permutations and combinations" on the web or in a math book.

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle et. al. - The question appears to be about power set (all possible subsets) not permutations (all possible orderings) as is the case in the supposed duplicate.  These are different concepts.

Answer (score 8):

I think the name of the thing you're looking for is 'power set'.  It sounded fun, so here's a crack at it.  I relied on [this very concise article](http://yubinkim.com/?p=87) for the algorithm.  I'm not sure if this is efficient (...actually, I'm sure this is inefficient) over large sets.

```
// answer the powerset of array: an array of all possible subarrays of the passed array
- (NSArray *)powerSet:(NSArray *)array {

    NSInteger length = array.count;
    if (length == 0) return [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSArray array]];

    // get an object from the array and the array without that object
    id lastObject = [array lastObject];
    NSArray *arrayLessOne = [array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,length-1)];

    // compute the powerset of the array without that object
    // recursion makes me happy
    NSArray *powerSetLessOne = [self powerSet:arrayLessOne];

    // powerset is the union of the powerSetLessOne and powerSetLessOne where
    // each element is unioned with the removed element
    NSMutableArray *powerset = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:powerSetLessOne];

    // add the removed object to every element of the recursive power set
    for (NSArray *lessOneElement in powerSetLessOne) {
        [powerset addObject:[lessOneElement arrayByAddingObject:lastObject]];
    }
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:powerset];
}
```

If you think this is a keeper, you could make it a category method on array and drop the parameter.  Test it like this...

```
NSLog(@"empty = %@", [self powerSet:[NSArray array]]);
NSLog(@"one item = %@", [self powerSet:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"a"]]);
NSLog(@"two items = %@", [self powerSet:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a", @"b", nil]]);
NSLog(@"three items = %@", [self powerSet:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a", @"b", @"c", nil]]);
```

I did only these tests, and the output looked good.  Spoiler alert: the three item test looks roughly like this on my console (with \n's removed):

> three items = ((),
>           (a),
>           (b),
>           (a,b),
>           (c),
>           (a,c),
>           (b,c),
>           (a,b,c))

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for, it needs to show also (b,a), (c,a), (c,b), (c,b,a), etc.

Comment: You're looking for permutations not combinations.