# How do I generate all permutations of a list of numbers?

Tags: c, arrays, permutation

How do I generate all possible permutations of a list of numbers in C?

As an example, `[1, 8, 12]` would generate

```
[1, 12, 8],
[12, 8, 1],
[12, 1, 8], ...
```

Comment: Do you mean all permutations?

Comment: Are you asking for an algorithm to find all of the permutations of a list? All combinations?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "generate all the numbers possible"?  What have you tried?  What's going wrong?  If this is homework, please use the 'homework' tag.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly your problem is. You got a list of numbers and want to list all ways of ordering these numbers? Or combining them each other to tuples, or tripels or whatnot? Could you be a bit more specific on your problem, please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Algorithm to generate all possible permutations of a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710713/algorithm-to-generate-all-possible-permutations-of-a-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this [Johnson-Trotter Algorithm](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Combinatorics/JohnsonTrotter.shtml) and applet it is exactly what you want.