# Python recursive lottery number combinations

Tags: python, recursion

So my problem is that in this lottery, you must select 6 numbers from the numbers 1 through 49. I have to do this **with recursion and without itertools**. I am really stuck as how else to continue to write my code.

Example input: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

Output:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6
>
> 1 2 3 4 5 7
>
> 1 2 3 4 6 7
>
> 1 2 3 5 6 7
>
> 1 2 4 5 6 7
>
> 1 3 4 5 6 7
>
> 2 3 4 5 6 7

So I have my base case and everything else except the **`else`** part:

```
def lottery( number ):
    if len(  number ) == 6:
        return number
    else:
```

I have tried this but it does not work:

```
    else:
        output = list()
        for i in range( len( numbers ) ):
            rem = lotto(     numbers[i+1:] )
            output.append(   numbers[   :i] + rem )     

    return output
```

Comment: can you specify the task more clearly - do you want every possible combination of 6 numbers from the range 1-49? (there will be quite a few!)

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109274/python-recursion-permutations

Comment: Actually, I believe this duplicate question provides better answers to the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python

Comment: No I only want those out put, it is different from others since 123456 will be the same as 123465. Sorry my English is not that good.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some issues with your variable names. Try:

```
def lottery(numbers):
    if len(numbers) == 6:
        return numbers

     output = list()
     for i in range(len(numbers)):
         rem = numbers[i+1:]
         output.append(numbers[:i]+rem)
    return output
```