# How can I create words with a certain length consisting of a and b?

Tags: python, list, recursion, cpu-word, string-length

I want to create a list of all words with a certain length (for example 1 to 3) that consist of two letters. So my output would be: 
a, b, aa, ab, ba, bb,.... 
but I am struggling to implement it recursively in python. What’s the right way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Noone will code for you here but, instead, help you when struggling. Can you post a code example? What have you tried so far?

Comment: a, b have only one letter

Comment: This can be done non-recursively, do you really have to use a recursive solution?

Comment: Exactly this is my problem. I have no clue how I should start with it. I‘m not expecting someone to code it for me, but something like a guideline or rough summary would already help me a lot :)

Comment: And no I don‘t have to do it recursively but I want to do it for practicing

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including sample input, sample output, and code for what you've tried based on your own research, if any

Comment: In Python, recursion is typically not the ideal solution (although it certainly has its place). Instead, Python focuses more heavily on iteration. Take a look a the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module, you should find the answer there.

Comment: Okay, I think product() seems to be the right one

Answer (score 1):

I combined both `itertools` and recursion in the following code:

```
from itertools import product,chain

ab = ['a', 'b']

def rec_prod(x):
    if x==1:
        return ab
    elif x==2:
        return list(product(ab, ab))
    else:
        return [tuple(chain((i[0],), i[1])) for i in product(ab, rec_prod(x-1))]

prod_range = lambda y: list(chain.from_iterable(rec_prod(j) for j in range(1, y+1)))
```

The first fuction recursively calculates all "words" of length x, the second one returns all words from length 1 to length y. It's a bit messy and not very efficient, but if you study the way I used recursion and the itertools function I used (`product` and `chain`) I'm sure you will learn something useful out of it.

Comment: Thank you! At least now I have an Idea of how it works

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use `itertools` for this, and it is a more pythonic way of approaching the problem.

```
list = ['a','b','c']

import itertools
for letter in itertools.permutations(list):
      list.append(' ',join(letter))
```

this will give you :

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'abc', 'acb', 'bac', 'bca', 'cab', 'cba']
```

[Python recursion permutations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109274/python-recursion-permutations)

This might also help you.

Comment: Thank you ! I‘ll try to understand it