# How to do recursion precisely in python including lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion, backtracking

I am a beginner trying to learn recursion in Python.
I want to print all the permutations of a given string.
For example:

**Input**: AABC

**Output**: AABC,AACB,ABAC,ABCA,ACAB,BAAC,BACA,BCAA,CAAB,CABA,CBAA

I have written the following code in Python using recursion.

```py
def foo(str,count):
    result = ""
    while(any(count)):
        for i in range(len(count)):
            if count[i]>0:
                count[i] -= 1
                result = str[i] + foo(str,count)
                print(result)
    return result

s = "AABC"
n = 4

c = {}
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i] in c:
        c[s[i]] += 1
    else:
        c[s[i]] = 1

str = list(c.keys())
count = list(c.values())
print(str,count)
foo(str,count)
print(count)
```

I am getting the output as follows:

> `['A', 'B', 'C'] [2, 1, 1]`
>
> `C`
>
> `BC`
>
> `ABC`
>
> `AABC`
>
> `[0, 0, 0]`

It implies that the code is handling only the first case at every level. How can I correct this code?
Any help would be wonderful.
Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python recursion permutations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109274/python-recursion-permutations)

Comment: What is `count` for?

Comment: Count is for storing the number of occurrences of each character in string.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are using `count` for but here is one way to do it recursively (not very optimal though). :

```
def foo(s,result):
    if len(result) == 4:
        print(result)
    if len(s) == 0:
        return
    for i in range(len(s)):
        new_s = s.copy()
        del new_s[i]
        foo(new_s,result + s[i])
s = list('AABC')
foo(s,'')
```

Output:

```
AABC
AACB
ABAC
ABCA
ACAB
ACBA
AABC
AACB
ABAC
ABCA
ACAB
ACBA
BAAC
BACA
BAAC
BACA
BCAA
BCAA
CAAB
CABA
CAAB
CABA
CBAA
CBAA
```

If you want distinct strings, you can add those to a `set`

Answer (score 1):

Your code look a bit messy and it's hard for me to understand how you tried to solve your problem with it. I tried to create as simple solution as possible to help you understand logic behind creating combinations of any kind of list.

```
def combinations(x):
    if len(x) == 1:
        yield x
    for idx, i in enumerate(x):
        for comb in combinations(x[:idx]+x[idx+1:]):
            yield i + comb

s = "AABC"
print(list(combinations(s))) # -> ['AABC', 'AACB', 'ABAC', 'ABCA', 'ACAB' ...
```

`x[:idx]+x[idx+1:]` here is just short of getting rid of `x`'s element at `idx`'s position. Add a comment if you have any questions so I can help you better understand my solution.

Comment: Thanks it works. But I am unfamiliar with enumerate.

Comment: If you're familiar with [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) here's how it could be implemented `zip(range(len(list)), list)`. Also [enumerate() docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out something which works but it gives duplicate answers because of multiple occurrences of character 'A', hence I used set() to get the desired answer.

```
def foo(s,l,result):
    if len(result)==4:
        l.append(result)
    for i in range(len(s)):
        foo(s[0:i]+s[i+1:],l,result+s[i])

s = "AABC"
l = []
r = foo(s,l,"")
print(list(set(l)))
```