# The simplest way to implement permutations without using any library?

Tags: python, function, permutation

How can I display all the permutations in a string or any other iterable in the most simplest way for a beginner...

```
def permutations(iterable):
       #code here
```

Ex. `Permutations("abc")`

Output: `"abc","acb","bac","bca","cba","cab"`

Comment: Use *recursion*

Comment: Select each of the input's elements as the start, then use recursion to create permutations of the rest.

Comment: There's some "roughly equivalent" code in the [`itertools` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) that might help. The Wikipedia article on the subject also describes some [algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Algorithms_to_generate_permutations).

Comment: This answers your question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13109403/7698734

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python recursion permutations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109274/python-recursion-permutations)

Comment: `itertools.permutations` is the way to go here, unless you want to implement it yourself.