# set of string permutation problem

Tags: java, algorithm, permutation

I got this set of string such as "12 13 2 1 444"

I want to generate all of different permutation of this set of integers.

I mean

```
"12 13 2 1 444"
"13 12 2 1 444"
"12 13 1 2 444"
"1 12 13 2 444"
.....
```

Could any one help me with Java?

Comment: no, it's finite set. sorry for not clear

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating all permutations of a given string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240080/generating-all-permutations-of-a-given-string) which is for strings (in Java), but that can *easily* be adapted to integers.

Comment: sorry, I changed it. It should be string. yes.

Comment: @Andy No, I'm not saying you should change to strings. Read that link, it gives answers to the same problem.

Comment: @Marcog, yes, after I check my question, it should be string .Thanks

Comment: @andy, post some code and we'll help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.  I think that the best way is to break this down into two steps:

1. Break the string down into its component parts.
2. Generate all permutations of those parts.

You can split the string into individual values by using the `String.split` method:

```
String[] allParts = inputString.split(' ');
```

Once you have this, you can generate all permutations with one of many permutation generation functions.  Leon's link will probably help out here.

Answer (score 1):

you need to do it recursively. Check http://programminggeeks.com/recursive-permutation-in-java/ as a guide

Comment: I don't think it needs to be recursive.

Comment: of course, everything recursive can be done iteratively, but it is just easier to do it recursively