# Generate all permutations in Java

Tags: java, permutation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating all permutations of a given string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240080/generating-all-permutations-of-a-given-string)

I have an array of arbitrary length in Java, and I would like to generate all possible permutations of them. The easy way to do this for a fixed length would be a series of nested for loops, but because the array is of unknown length, that is not an option here. Is there a straightforward way to accomplish this in Java?

Comment: just type `[java] permutation` in the search box...

Comment: If it's an array, you can use array.length; if it's a List, you can use list.size().  I don't understand "not an option".

Comment: @duffymo: So I would like to see you generating the nested for loops on the fly once you get the array length in the code ...

Comment: checkout guava's Collections2.permutation: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.java?r=HEAD#537

Comment: @JanZyka - It's nothing to do with nested loops, you just need a stack data structure. At the end of the day all flow control is just ifs and gotos.

Comment: Irony man :) I just said that even though you know array.length you can't really generate array.length nested loops on the fly in your code.

Answer (score 3):

Use a recursive function, instead of loops. Each time you call the method should be on a smaller portion of the array and stop when length = 0. This [link](http://programminggeeks.com/recursive-permutation-in-java/) should help you design your function.

Answer (score 0):

It may or may not be optimal as far as performance goes, but if you're looking for a way to do it with writing relatively little code and having it be clear and maintainable, you want a recursive method rather than nested loops.