# Alogrithm to getting all combines of x-letters

Tags: java, algorithm, permutation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating all permutations of a given string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240080/generating-all-permutations-of-a-given-string)

I´m looking for a algorithm which returns me a List of all possible combines of x-letters.

Example: 3 letters. (A,B,C)

- A B C
- A C B
- B C A
- B A C
- C B A
- C A B

I want to do this up to 4-5 letters with a algorithm in Java.

Comment: You're after permutations .. there are several libraries/example on how to do this ... just google java string permutations

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Algorithms_to_generate_permutations

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is all **permutations** of a string.

Here is an example from [Princeton cs](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/Permutations.java.html) done in Java.

Answer (score 0):

```
void printAllLetterSequences(String prefix, int length) {
    System.out.println(prefix);
    if (prefix.size() < length)
        for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'D'; c++)
            printAllLetterSequences(prefix + c, length);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.
your algorithm returns a list of characters which contains combines with 3 characters when i need 4.

And I only want to get each character ones in the combine. For example "ABBA" not.

Comment: @user959456 Better check the duplicate question mentioned in comments (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240080/generating-all-permutations-of-a-given-string). It's more universal as it works with any kind of character sequences.