# String Permutations Java

Tags: java, algorithm, permutation

I need to get all of the permutations of a string, but with a twist. I need to get the permutations, but at different lengths.
Like this:
the permutations of AB would be:

A

B

AA

BB

AB

BA

I can get the permutations of a string, with fixed lengths, but I'm stuck on this.

Comment: Why don't you put your solution in a loop with a length from 0 to your string's length ?

Comment: @dystroy You wont get all of the combinations with that.

Comment: I would modify @dystroy to include a maximum length, since you may not want to be limited to the length of the input String.

Comment: Are characters different in the string or there's repetitions?

Comment: It looks to me like this is multicombination, not permutation. Take a look at the algorithm [here](http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/combinatorial-algorithms.html#multicombinations). Just rerun the algorithm with different string lengths via a `for` loop. The algorithm itself is very much like counting. See [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12288895/646634).

Answer (score 1):

```java
public void processPermutations(String s) {
  for (int i=1; i<s.length; i++) {
    String substring = s.substring(0, i);
    // Generate and process the permutations of the substring here...
  }
}
```

Comment: That wont work, for the permutations of 123 results in

1
12
21
123
132
213
231
312
321

I need to get 13 31 32 23, ect. as well.

Comment: This will not get him all the permutations. If the string is ABC with this code he will never get AC, BC and C

Comment: @Christina And AA BB CC AAA also required.

Comment: @Roman, you're right. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Christina Don't forget repetitions within permutations you didn't posted.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
public List<String> getPermutations(String s) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (s.length() > 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            //Create a string that has all the characters of s except the ith one
            String smallerString = s.substring(0,i) + s.substring(i + 1, s.length());
            result.addAll(getPermutations(smallerString));

            //Get permutations involving a single character appearing multiple times,
            //ie. AA, AAA, AAAA, etc.
            String repeatString = new String();
            for (int j = 1; j <= s.length(); j++) {
                repeatString = repeatString + s.charAt(i);
                result.add(repeatString);
            }
        }
    }

    //Add all the permutations using all the string's characters to the list here.
    return result;
}
```

Try not to think of the complexity of that however ;)

Comment: You're right, I used s.size() instead of s.length() by mistake. It's fixed now.

Comment: I haven't added the actual code which will get the permutations of a string using all its characters since he already knows how to do this. This should be added in the part which says //Add all the permutations using all the string's characters to the list here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the combinations of the string first into a descending number of buckets, then permute on each combination bucket. For example, if your string has 3 characters:

Combinations of "ABC" choose 3 = 1
Combinations of "ABC" choose 2 = 3
Combinations of "ABC" choose 1 = 3

Thus, you need to find the permutations of each of these 7 cases. In pseudocode:

```
int lenString = s.length
int[] all_permutations = new array
for( buckets = 1 to lenString ){
    int[] c = Combinations( s, buckets )
    int[] p = Permutations( c )
    all_permutations += p   
}
```