# String permutation using for loops

Tags: java, for-loop, permutation

I have to print all the possible permutations of the given input string.

Using the code below I get  `aaaa  bbb ccc`  now in next iteration I want to print  `aaa aab aac`. `aba  aca`  and so on. Please guide me about it.

```
String s = "abc";
char ch;
ArrayList<Character> input = new ArrayList<Character>();

public static void main (String [] args)
{
  String  s= "abc";
  int count ; 
  char ch;
  ArrayList<Character> input = new ArrayList<Character>();
  for (int i=0; i < s.length(); i++)
  {
    ch = s.charAt(i);
    input.add(ch);         
  }       


  for (int i=0; i <= input.size(); i++)
  {
    for(int j=0; j < input.size(); j++)
    {
      System.out.print(input.get(i));
    } 
    System.out.println();
  } 
}
```

Comment: Why are you using an `ArrayList<Character>` to store String characters while every character can be read using `s.charAt(i)`?

Comment: @BackSlash  i have  placed specific string here  , but input is not specific   that can be  abc123  etc  .

Comment: And what exactly is the desired pattern?

Comment: well, loop until `i` and `j` are less than `s.length()` and use `s.charAt(i)` instead of `input.get(i)`, `ArrayList` makes no sense in this specific case

Comment: for example input : ab12  so output : aaaa  aaab aaa1 aaa2 aaba aabb aab1 aab2 ,first iteration 3 a's  second iteration 2 a's and ba +bb, b1 +b2 ...

Comment: Your description of the pattern is very poor - I still can't understand it. Please drastically improve your description or your question is likely to be closed as unanswerable. Can you edit your question include the complete expected pattern for the input `abc`?

Comment: ok let me do  an image to clear it

Comment: @DuncanJones I think he simply wants to have a bruteforce output for every input he has, for `ab` he wants to print out `aa` `bb` `ab` `ba`, for `abc` he wants `aaa` `bbb` `ccc` `aab` `aac` `aba` `abb` etc

Comment: @DuncanJones yes,,  bruteforce?

Comment: Sounds like you want every possible *permutation* of the input characters.

Comment: yes , answer by  seniorJD is very much related  as we were told in class  .but i had totally forgot the basic idea to do it .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating all permutations of a given string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240080/generating-all-permutations-of-a-given-string)

Comment: @DuncanJones What is described has nothing to do with *permutations*.

Comment: @Howard What is the correct terminology then? Based on the comments above, it appears the OP wants every possible combination of the input characters.

Answer (score 3):

You can use recursive function. Example

```
private static String text = "abcd";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    loopPattern(text, 0, "");
}

private static void loopPattern(String source, int index, String res) {
    if (source == null || source.length() == 0) {
    return;
    }
    if (index == source.length()) {
        System.out.println(res);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < source.length(); i++) {
        loopPattern(source, index + 1, res + source.charAt(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A recursive version which is not dependent of the number of characters:

```
class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        if(args.length != 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Usage: java Test <string>");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String input = args[0];

        iterate(input, "", input.length());
    }

    public static void iterate(String input, String current, int level)
    {
        if(level == 0)
        {
            System.out.println(current);
            return;
        }

        for(int i=0; i < input.length(); i++)
        {
            iterate(input, current + input.charAt(i), level-1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In current implementation, you should use:

```
for (int i=0; i <= input.size(); i++) {
   for(int j=0; j < input.size(); j++) {
      for(int k=0; k < input.size(); k++) {
         System.out.print(input.get(i));
         System.out.print(input.get(j));
         System.out.print(input.get(k));
         System.out.println();
      }
   }
}
```

But IMHO it is better to use `s.charAt(i)` instead of `input.get(i)`.

Comment: It sounds like the OP wants every possible permutation of the input characters. In which case, this solution doesn't scale because it requires one `for` loop per character.

Comment: this is very much related to what  i was told  in class   ,  i just did not  try it same time and totally lost the idea . this is really helpful

Comment: dude this is not the correct solution