# Algorithm of Permutation with Limited Repetition

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, math, permutation

Is there an algorithm to list out all the permutations with a limited repetition? If there is an existing Java library, it would be so nice!

Let's say we have 3 items `{A, B, C}`. We want a permutation of 2 items. It would be <sub>3</sub>P<sub>2</sub>:

```
{A, B}
{A, C}
{B, A}
{B, C}
{C, A}
{C, B}
```

But if we allow a maximum repetition of twice. How it would be like? (i don't really know.)

I try to imaging we are getting a permutation of 2 from the set `{A, A, B, B, C, C}`. It would be <sub>6</sub>P<sub>2</sub> = 30. But we have to take away those duplicates. I have done it by hand and it is 9. I don't know how to calculate 9 from maths.

```
{A, A}
{A, B}
{A, C}
{B, B}
{B, A}
{B, C}
{C, C}
{C, A}
{C, B}
```

*(In fact <sub>3</sub>P<sub>2</sub> with a repetition of 2 is not a good example. It is because there are only 2 elements in the permutations. Therefore, there are no differences between an unlimited repetition. <sub>4</sub>P<sub>3</sub> with a repetition of 2 would be a nicer example. But it would be tough to list out all the permutations.)*

A better example for illustration: <sub>4</sub>P<sub>3</sub> of set `{A, B, C, D}`:

```
{A, B, C}
{A, B, D}
{A, C, B}
{A, C, D}
{A, D, B}
{A, D, C}
... repeat for permutations starting from {B, ... }
... repeat for permutations starting from {C, ... }
... repeat for permutations starting from {D, ... }
```

And <sub>4</sub>P<sub>3</sub> of set `{A, B, C, D}` with a repetition limit of 2:

```
{A, A, B}
{A, A, C}
{A, A, D}

{A, B, A}
{A, B, B}
{A, B, C}
{A, B, D}

{A, C, A}
{A, C, B}
{A, C, C}
{A, C, D}

{A, D, A}
{A, D, B}
{A, D, C}
{A, D, D}

... repeat for permutations starting from {B, ... }
... repeat for permutations starting from {C, ... }
... repeat for permutations starting from {D, ... }
```

[Here](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/probability/permutations-repeated-items.php) is a webpage talking about similar thing. But it seems it requires <sub>n</sub>P<sub>n</sub> (selecting all the elements). Also, i still need an algorithm to generate and list out the permutations.

Thanks for your helps!

---

For programming implementation, in fact there is a "not smart" approach.

For set `{A, B, C, D}`, keep a complementary array `int used[0, 0, 0, 0]`, which are the numbers of times each element is used. Increment the count every time an element is chosen, and pass a copy of the array forward (down the call tree). Then with the recursive approach inspired [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4240323/1884546), alter it to allow unlimited repetition (by *not* deleting the selected one from the element set), and add an `if (used[i] <= LIMIT)` checking statement after `for`.

This is "not smart" and not good enough because we need a complementary array and require checking the used number every time.

Comment: Wouldn't generating the permutations of `{A, B, C}` (of any length) allowing a single repetition of each element be the same as generating the permutations of `{A, A, B, B, C, C}` of the same length?

Comment: For length = 3, if elements of `{A, A, B, B, C, C}` are distinct, i.e. `A != A`, it would be P(6, 3), and having duplicated `{A, A, B}` and `{A, A, B}`, which is unwanted.

Comment: Technically speaking, a set cannot allow repetition

Comment: @ricard.m.o., Hmm... do you mean nPr / permutation cannot deal with repeated element? If so, we may have to think in another way.

Comment: A permutation is a particular ordered sequence where elements appear only once. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#In_combinatorics

Comment: @ricard.m.o. Yes. But if we search "permutation with repetition" in google, there are some people studying this special case. However all resources i have found so far works only for nPn (not nPr).

Comment: I believe this is called a combination

Answer (score 1):

I have come into this problem before with generating all the possible partitions of a set. This is essentially the same concept as what you are trying to do. (All combinations of a given size is the same as the set of partitions of that size) I found [this](http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~orlovm/papers/partitions.pdf) paper that gave a very fast non recursive algorithm to generate these combinations without any repetition along with a c++ implementation.

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers, if the link becomes unavailable, then this answer has no value whatsoever. Try to incorporate the main idea into your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is a little late, but I have a [Java Combinatorics](https://github.com/ctrimble/combinatorics) library up on GitHub that will do this.  Here is the basic usage:

Include the dependency in your project:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.xiantrimble.combinatorics</groupId>
  <artifactId>combinatorics</artifactId>
  <version>0.2.0</version>
<dependency>
```

Then iterate the permutations by getting a virtual collection from the combinatoric factory:

```
import com.xiantrimble.combinatorics.CombinatoricFactory;
import com.xiantrimble.combinatorics.CombinatoricFactoryImpl;
import com.xiantrimble.combinatorics.Combinatoric;
...
int k = 6;
int[] domain = {1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4};
// create a factory.
CombinatoricFactory factory = new CombinatoricFactoryImpl();
Combinatoric<Integer> permutations = factory.createPermutations(k,  domain);

for( Integer[] permutation : permutations ) {
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(permutation));
}
```

The code does not do a dictionary order, but is instead geared toward trying to minimize the change between consecutive elements, so keep that in mind.  Also, there are some improvements in the 0.3.0-SNAPSHOT version, which is available on Sonatype's snapshot repository.

Answer (score 0):

See [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002198006680025X) that finds a theoretical formula for the number of answers.
The paper information is: "Permutations with limited repetitions" by Roberto Frucht from Journal of Combinatorial Theory with doi of 10.1016/S0021-9800(66)80025-X

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers, if the link becomes unavailable, then this answer has no value whatsoever. Try to incorporate the main idea into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of permutations as binary carry processing. For example, 0000,0001,0010 in binary.

```
 public static int[][] permutation(int size,int carryNum) {
    if(size == 0)
        return new int[0][0];

    int s = size - 1;
    int cNum = carryNum - 1;
    int s1 = 1;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        s1 = s1 * carryNum ;
    }
    int[][] commands = new int[s1][size];
    for (int i = 1; i < s1; i++) {

        for (int j = s; j >= 0; j--) {
            commands[i][j] = commands[i - 1][j];
        }

        for (int j = s; j >= 0; j--) {
            int last = commands[i][j];
            if ((last + 1) > cNum) {
                commands[i][j] = 0;
            } else {
                commands[i][j] = last + 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return commands;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] s = permutation(7,3);
    for (int[] command : s) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(command));
    }
}

output result:

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]
          .
          .
          .
[0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2]

[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```