# What are some ways I can relate an index to an N length string?

Tags: java

Here's the situation:

I have 36 characters to choose from, a-z and 0-9.

```
char[] alphabet = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
```

And using an index, we want to create all possible strings of length N, from N = 1 to N = 2.

A length of 1 is rather simple,

```
private String generateString(int index){    
    if (index < 36){
        char word = alphabet[index];
        return String.valueOf(word);
    }

    if ( index < 1332) {
        //lost
    }
}
```

But what if we wanted a length of 2, well we can assume that all words of length 2 will have an index of > 36 and < 1332 (36 + (36^2)). But I am lost on how to relate these indexes to a  word with length 2, and making sure all possible word combinations are hit.

I think there is a mathematical way to accomplish this, but I am just not seeing it.

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240080/generating-all-permutations-of-a-given-string).

Comment: Do you mean anything like: `553 -> "tx", 678 -> "yd"`, and so on?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got your question right. Do you want all combinations of letters in various string lengths (like in a [brute force attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack))? Then this might help you.

If your alphabet consists just of `0-z`, then you can make use of Java's [Integer.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString-int-int-) method providing a radix of 36, and just do some counting and padding:

```
void start(int lengthFrom, int lengthTo) {
    for (int length = lengthFrom; length <= lengthTo; length++) {
        for (int i=0; i < Math.pow(36, length); i++) {
            result(String.format("%" + length + "s", Integer.toString(i, 36)).replace(' ', '0'));
        }
    }
}

void result(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

If you need more flexibility in regard to your alphabet, check this code. Here you can add whatever characters, because it just fills them recursively from left to right:

```
char[] alphabet = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();

void start(int lengthFrom, int lengthTo) {
    for (int length = lengthFrom; length <= lengthTo; length++) {
        char[] chars = new char[length];
        fill(chars, 0);
    }
}

void fill(char[] chars, int pos) {
    if (chars.length == pos) {
        result(new String(chars));
        return;
    }
    for (char c : alphabet) {
        chars[pos] = c;
        fill(chars, pos+1);
    }
}

void result(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

This method uses [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion). All recursive algorithms can be transformed to iterative algorithms; which usually consume less memory but are also less easy to read.

If you want an "index" for your Strings, you could build it using the `result()` method as the passed strings are ordered.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you're not talking about this, right?

```
Integer.parseInt(word, 36);
Integer.toString(index, 36);
```

So that

```
Integer.parseInt("1z", 36); // int(71)
Integer.toString(71, 36);   // "1z"
```

Answer (score 0):

For the two letter words, create a mapping `[1,2,...,1296] -> ["00","01",...,"zz"]` by folding the 1d index into a 2d one of size 36, ie. `[1,2,...,1296] -> [(1,1), (2,1), (3,1), ..., (36,36)]`:

```
private String generateTwoLetterString(final int index) {
    if(index > 1296) 
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("index is greater than 1296");

    int j = (int) Math.ceil(index/36f);
    int i = index % 36 == 0 ? 36 : index % 36;

    return String.format("%s%s", alphabet[j-1], alphabet[i-1]);
}
```

Comment: If you look at @steffen's shorter answer, my function above will output the same as `Integer.toString(index-1, 36)`.