# Java recursion to find all the possible permutations & combinations in Arraylist quits too early

Tags: java, for-loop, recursion, arraylist, permutation

I'm writing a recursive permutations program in Java to find all the possible permutation of the Strings in an Arraylist. 
I know there are a lot of posts similar to this, but I haven't found one that addresses this issue specifically.

The problem I have with my code is that it only runs the first permutation and then quits

I know that it's doing this because every time it is called, an item is removed but the indexes shift so its only doing one call per element, but I don't know how to fix it. I've tried changing the for-loop conditions, removing the element at different spots, adding base cases, but everything seems to only make it worse. As it is now, the input`[w,h,a,t]`would return an arrayList with elements `[what,hat,at,t]`. The expected output is all the permutations of the four letters.

Where do I go from here? I know I'm close but I've been stuck on this for several days

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
public class wordFinder {
    static ArrayList<String> permutations = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static String findPermutations(ArrayList<String> letterArray) {
        String prefix = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < letterArray.size(); i++) {
            String temp = letterArray.remove(i);
            prefix = temp + findPermutations(letterArray);
            permutations.add(prefix);
        }
        return prefix;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a for-loop and a recursive call?

Comment: first check whether you really wanna use for loops if you want a recursion

Comment: @shinjw yes, there _is_ a recursive call. @azurefrog a recursive function can have a `for` loop, there's nothing inherently wrong with that

Comment: What is your current output?

Comment: @ÓscarLópez It is true that there is nothing inherently wrong with that in general, but in this case the OP is both modifying `letterArray` on each time through the loop, and also passing the same reference down to be emptied in the recursive call.  The second time through the outermost for-loop will (I expect) have an empty `letterArray`, and fall through the `i < letterArrays.size()` check.  Since the for-loop as written will always only execute once, I question the logic in having it.

Comment: azurefrog is right, after the recursive call, `letterArray` is empty. The reason for the for-loop is to append `prefix` to the recursive call for every element, but that's not happening because the indexes shift

Comment: Check your logic. You recursion happens over and over and over before permutations.add(prefix) is ever reached

Comment: There's a good explanation of finding all permutations of a string [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240080/generating-all-permutations-of-a-given-string), the answers there should give you some ideas on how to write a recursive method like you are trying to.  You could use one of the solutions there, and write an outer method which calls the recursive method, giving it a succession of shorter and shorter substrings, until you've gotten all permutations of all lengths.

Comment: @Infinite Recursion expected output is all the permutations of the four letters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Note:** Using `ArrayList`s like this for alphabets, along with `for`-loop and recursion is not optimal and **extremely expensive** in term of resources. This solution is only to illustrate the concept of recursion as mentioned in the question.

---

As you are looking for the recursive solution, to understand the concept, here it is.

The primary idea is that as you keep removing an alphabet from the `ArrayList`, keep adding them to another list so that they don't get lost and use both the lists to find all the possible combinations.

### Code:

```
static ArrayList<String> permutations = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> letterArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    letterArray.add("w");
    letterArray.add("h");
    letterArray.add("a");
    letterArray.add("t");
    wordFinder(new ArrayList<String>(), letterArray);
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(permutations));
}

public static void wordFinder(ArrayList<String> sub,
        ArrayList<String> letterArray) {
    permutations.add(sub.toString());
    if (letterArray.size() != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < letterArray.size(); i++) {
            ArrayList<String> prefix = new ArrayList<String>(sub);
            prefix.add(letterArray.get(i));
            ArrayList<String> postfix = new ArrayList<String>(letterArray);
            postfix.remove(i);
            wordFinder(prefix, postfix);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I never thought to split the original array into pre- and post- arrays, I just kept trying to create a temp and modify the original one. This is a lot neater

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a recursion for that.

You can do this by simple iterations:
Try:

```
public class wordFinder {
    public static ArrayList<String> findPermutations(ArrayList<String> letterArray) {
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < letterArray.size(); i++) {
            String current = letterArray.get(i);
            for (int j = i +1; j < letterArray.size(); j++) {
                current = current + letterArray.get(j); 
            }
            result.add(current);

        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

This will return an array of Strings just how you expect!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for the recursive solution. Its not so much the conceptualization, but the implementation that I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

You should say thanks to @Cesar Villasana. Because i just converted hi solution to recursive one. Here is this code and you will get your desired output.

```
public class Test {

         /*static int i=0;
         static ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
         public static void findPermutations(ArrayList<String> letterArray) {

             //int i=0;
             if(i>=letterArray.size()){
                 return;

             }else{

                 String current = letterArray.get(i);
                 for (int j = i +1; j < letterArray.size(); j++) {
                     current = current + letterArray.get(j); 
                 }
                 result.add(current);

             i++;
             findPermutations(letterArray);
         }

         }*/
        public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> generatePerm(ArrayList<String> original) {
            if (original.size() == 0) { 
              ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
              result.add(new ArrayList<String>());
              return result;
            }
            String firstElement = original.remove(0);
            ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> returnValue = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
            ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> permutations = generatePerm(original);
            for (ArrayList<String> smallerPermutated : permutations) {
              for (int index=0; index <= smallerPermutated.size(); index++) {
                ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>(smallerPermutated);
                temp.add(index, firstElement);
                returnValue.add(temp);
              }
            }
            return returnValue;
          }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<String > b=new ArrayList<String>();
        b.add("w");
        b.add("h");
        b.add("a");
        b.add("t");
    Test t=new Test();
//  t.findPermutations(b);
    //  System.out.println(t.result);
    System.out.println(t.generatePerm(b));
    }

}
```

Comment: This still only gives me the original ArrayList with one element subtracted each time, output should be n! permutations of all the letters