# Every Unique Ordering of a For Loop in Java

Tags: java, for-loop

I have a for loop that I would like to loop through in every unique ordering.

For example if I want to loop through the set of numbers = [1,2,3]
I can loop through these numbers in the order of 1 -> 2 - > 3, but I could also do 3->2->1.  I would like to loop through my set of numbers in every possible unique ordering.

I want to get this output

i = 1,2,3

i = 1,3,2

i = 2,1,3

i = 2,3,1

i = 3,1,2

i = 3,2,1

So ideally it would be two for loops.  The outer loop would change the ordering of the numbers and the inner loop would iterate through the numbers.  I'm having a hard time thinking of a way to do this.  Is there any straightforward means that might accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the set arbitrary in size, and is it always 1...n? I don't think there's a straightforward way for all n. But google around for "all **permutations** java" and you'll find some ideas.

Comment: Google for "generate permutations java"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240080/generating-all-permutations-of-a-given-string