# permutations of integers(no duplication)

Tags: java, algorithm

I want a program that takes in an 8 digits number and return all permutations of it.

For instance, `12345678` should return `12345687, 12345768, 12345786 .. 87654321`.

My idea is to do this:

First put every digit as a element in an array and then:

```
for (int y = 0; y < digits; y++)
    for (int x = 0; x < digits; x++)
        for (int u = 0; u < digits; u++)
            for (int m = 0; m < digits; m++)
                for (int z = 0; z < digits; z++)
                    for (int b = 0; b < digits; b++)
                        for (int c = 0; c < digits; c++)
                            for (int d = 0; d < digits; d++)
                            {
                                if (!(y == x || y == u || y == m
                                    || y == z || y == b || y == c
                                    || y == d || x == u || x == m
                                    || x == z || x == b || x == c
                                    || x == d || u == m || u == z
                                    || u == b || u == c || u == d
                                    || m == z || m == b || m == c
                                    || m == d || z == b || z == c
                                    || z == d || b == c || b == d || c == d))
                                {

                                    holding[co] = (a1[y] * 10000000)
                                                + (a1[x] * 1000000)
                                                + (a1[u] * 100000)
                                                + (a1[m] * 10000)
                                                + (a1[z] * 1000)
                                                + (a1[b] * 100)
                                                + (a1[c] * 10)
                                                +  a1[d];

                                    co++;
                                }
                            }
```

And get all of the result into an array. Sort the array and get rid of the same elements (like if input is `11223344` then there will be same elements).

But the problem is I actually want to print all of permutations of numbers from `10000000` to `20000000`. This idea works too slow. Does anyone know how to do it more quickly?

Comment: "All permutations of numbers from 10000000 to 2000000" - perish the thought, all the paper in the world won't hold the result.

Comment: Or do you mean those numbers resulting from the permutations of the digits 1 to 8 where the first digit is 1?

Comment: to hold all permutations from 1 million to 2 million is the factorial of 1 million way too big for any collection in any programming language, even if outputting them to a file it would take up gigabytes.  what exactly do you want to do with the permutations?

Comment: Its 10M to 20M. I lost one zero, but see OP.

Comment: I found 10000000! = 1.202423401×10^65657059

Comment: Well, there are 10 million numbers in the range you are interested in. Each number has 40320 permutations. So, you are looking at 403.2 billion numbers. If you spend 1 millisecond to print out one number (in reality, it take longer), then it will take you about 13 years to print them all out. If additionally you spend 1 millisecond to produce one permutation, that'll take you another 13 years. How fast exactly do you need it to be? I mean, how old are you?

Comment: @Sdiao has to clarify if he/she wants permutations in range or permutations of 1 string only. Permuting numbers of 3 digits produces 3!, but permuting all numbers in 0-999 is 1000! There is a significance difference.

Comment: Like everyone else, I'm not clear on what exactly you're looking for.  However, the algorithm you've chosen may be the wrong one.  You have 8 nested loops and each one runs 8 times, so the loop body will run 8^8 = 16777216 times.  However, the number of permutations is 8! = 40320.  That means you're doing about 416 times as much work as you should need to do.

Comment: @ajb you can skip inner loops by testing the outer loop counters. But the recursive algorithm (although not without overhead) is at least more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about recursively, like they suggest over here?

[Generating all permutations of a given string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240080/generating-all-permutations-of-a-given-string)

Logic has been improved slightly due to Pham's suggestions.  I think this is O(n) now...  Let me know if someone sees differently.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Main {

        static ArrayList<Integer> numbersList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        static ArrayList<String> prefixList = new ArrayList<String>();

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String number = "83241232";

            permutation(number);

            System.out.printf("Found %d unique permutations!%n", numbersList.size());
            for(int i=0; i<numbersList.size(); i++)
            {
                System.out.printf("%d%n", numbersList.get(i));
            }
        }

        public static void permutation(String str) { 
            permutation("", str); 
        }

        private static void permutation(String prefix, String str) {
            int n = str.length();
            if (n == 0) 
            {
                if(!prefixList.contains(prefix))
                {
                    prefixList.add(prefix);
                    numbersList.add(Integer.parseInt(prefix));
                }
            }
            else {
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    permutation(prefix + str.charAt(i), str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i+1, n));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Well, he asked: "I want a program that takes in an 8 digits number and return all permutations of it."  This program does that.  I don't understand how this is not an answer to his question.  Besides... you need 50 reputation to comment and I don't have that :/  Maybe you could up-vote my answer to help me get there?  :P

Comment: This will return all permutations, with duplication, so it is not a correct answer, however, you can add small changes to make it correct!

Comment: I added a check to remove the duplicates.  I initially had no duplicates because my input string had no duplicates, but once I changed the string to have two identical digits, the duplicates were apparent.  Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: This answer now is correct, but you just increase the total time complexity from O(n) to O(n^2)(n is number of permutation), which is not good. There is one better way, look at this line `permutation(prefix + str.charAt(i), str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i+1, n));`  you can check if the character `i` append to the `prefix` is already used before for example: prefix + 1 only need to be added once, if it is used before, you can skip this, this step will even reduce the time complexity for your program.

Comment: I think I've added logic to improve run time to O(n) now.  Please let me know if you think differently

Answer (score 0):

for one too many loops
this is a much easier example and this is just for a 10 digit array you can modify this to go through all 1000000 or how ever much you need it to, although it takes a while.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 *
 * @author David
 */
public class Permutations {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void permutations(int[] chararr,int start, int end)
    {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(chararr));
        if (start<end)
        {
            int i,j;
            for(i=end-2; i>=start; i--)
            {
                for(j=i+1; j<end; j++)
                {
                    Swap(chararr,i,j);
                    permutations(chararr,i+1,end);
                }
                Rotate_Left(chararr,i,end);
            }
        }
    }
    private static void Swap(int[] chararr,int i,int j)
    {
        int t;
        t = chararr[i];
        chararr[i] = chararr[j];
        chararr[j] = t;
    }

    private static void Rotate_Left(int[] chararr,int start,int end)
    {
        int tmp = chararr[start];
        for (int i=start; i < end-1; i++)
        {
            chararr[i] = chararr[i+1];
        }
        chararr[end-1] = tmp;
    }         

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int[] array = new int[10];
        for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++)
            array[x] = x+1;
        permutations(array,0,array.length);

    }

}
```

Comment: Just a note this will give all valid permutations, however it does not check for duplicate numbers in the array, to get rid of dupes from the input is easy.