# Not able to understand string permutation Java code

Tags: java, string, permutation

I have this working code to print string permutations without repetitions, but not able to wrap my head around how is it working as in logic. Any suggestions will be really helpful.

```
private static void permutation(String input, String sofar) {
        if (input.equals("")) {
            System.out.println(count + " " + sofar);
            count++;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            char c = input.charAt(i);
            if (input.indexOf(c, i + 1) != -1)
                continue;
            permutation(input.substring(0, i) + input.substring(i + 1), sofar+c);
        }
    }
```

Function call:

```
String input = "ABBCD";
permutation(input, "");
```

Comment: Consider using a debugger and stepping through the code.

Comment: Tried . but still not able to make sense. Recursive calls are driving me crazy. So, I am hoping if someone can say what is being done here on broad level in few lines. That will be very kind.

Comment: re write it to be iterative. Any recursive algorithm can be implemented iteratively

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating all permutations of a given string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240080/generating-all-permutations-of-a-given-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
```

The above for loop is doing the magic

Input ABCD

Iterations

input: BCD  sofar: A  .... recursion goes on

input: ACD  sofar: B  ....

input: ABD  sofar: C  ....

input: ABC  sofar: D   .....

Hope this helps

Comment: Precisely this is what I was missing. Stupidity at its best. :(

Comment: There is a bit more to it than just that.

Answer (score 2):

Just remember that recursion is usually a stop condition, and an attempt to solve a smaller problem using the recursive call, under the assumption that the recursion works.

I've commented the code so you can replace that with your copy to keep track of what it's doing when you get back to it. Add your own comments once you understand as they'll help you follow what happens:

**Part 1:** The basic condition / stop condition:

```
if (input.equals("")) {
    System.out.println(count + " " + sofar);
    count++;
}
```

This part stops the recursion and returns a result, the base case being an empty string, which has a single permutation that is also an empty string.

**Part 2:** Iterating smaller problems.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    char c = input.charAt(i);
    // ...
    permutation(input.substring(0, i) + input.substring(i + 1), sofar+c);
}
```

This part uses the recursive call on a smaller (by one character) string, to solve the problem. It calls the same string omitting a character it prepends to whatever following results it generates. We **know** the call generates all permutations (that's our assumption). So we now know what the recursion does.

**Part 2.1:** The de-duplicating "if":

This is probably the trickiest part here...

```
if (input.indexOf(c, i + 1) != -1)
    continue;
```

Let's figure this out. What it means, is: "try and find a character the same as the one selected, and if one exists, skip this iteration and it's generated solutions".

Think of a word like "ABBA" it will skip the first "A" and "B", but not the last ones. Why? Well, since order of similar characters does not matter (if we tag the character `A1` `B1` `B2` `A2`, and now replace them: `A2` `B2` `B1` `A1`, this is still the same word, so there is only one permutation for words like "AA", since `A1` `A2` is the same as `A2` `A1`.

Taking the **last** characters is easier, since we don't need to maintain a list of the characters we already used in this iteration.

The full code with basic comments:

```
private static void permutation(String input, String sofar) {

        if (input.equals("")) {
            // this is the stop condition
            // the only permutation of "" is ""
            System.out.println(count + " " + sofar);
            // this counts how many permutations were outputted.
            count++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            // this loop basically means "take every
            // possible character, and append permutations of all
            // other characters to it.
            char c = input.charAt(i);
            if (input.indexOf(c, i + 1) != -1)
                // this makes sure we only take a single "A" or "B"
                // character in words like "ABBA", since selecting
                // the same character would create duplicates
                continue;

            // this creates a new string without the selected character
            // and under the assumption the recursion works
            // appends all permutations of all other characters
            // to it
            permutation(input.substring(0, i) + input.substring(i + 1), sofar+c);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (input.equals("")) {
     System.out.println(count + " " + sofar);
     count++;
}
```

This step is passed as the input is not `""`. Note that you could simply use `input.empty()` here. The only thing to remember here is that `count` have not been incremented.

---

```
for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
```

This will, loop over all character of the `input`

---

```
char c = input.charAt(i);
if (input.indexOf(c, i + 1) != -1)
```

This check if the next character is equal to the current one, if it does then it will jump directly to the next `iteration`(the next character) using the `continue` keyword.

---

If it does not, then it will  recall the method (We call that `recursivity`), passing in the string without the current `char`. But giving it back to `sofar`.

```
permutation(input.substring(0, i) + input.substring(i + 1), sofar+c);
```

---

Now in the case where input is empty,

The count of non-distinct `character` will be printed + all these `character`.