# Algorithms to find permutation of a string

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures, permutation

Can anyone suggest specific algorithms to find different permutations of a given string except recursion technique

Comment: If you want iteration, instead of recursion, note that every solution which can be written as a recursion can be written in an iterative way as mentioned by Amnon Shochot in an answer below. So I would recommend you write down the recursive algorithm and then work out the iterative solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can find how to do it with recursion in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240080/generating-all-permutations-of-a-given-string).

Then you can port this code to use stacks instead of relying on the thread stack used by the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this problem, if you don't want to use recursion, can be via dynamic programming, something like this:

```
list = originalString.split('')
index = (0,0)
list = [""]
for iteration n in 1 to y:
  index = (index[1], len(list))
  for string s in list.subset(index[0] to end):
    for character c in originalString:
      list.add(s + c)
```