# Arranging operands and operators to get number

Tags: java, algorithm, math, operators, expression

I have one given number n, 4 operands a1, a2, a3, a4, and 4 operators +, -, *, / in Java. I need to test if I can arrange operands with operators so that they form a mathematical expression which equals the given number, or at least is closest in value with it. I don't need to use all operands and each operand can be used only once. I am not asking someone to give me code just to explain if it is possible, or if there is some library for this. Thanks.

Comment: if you are asked to do so it should be possible. you might want to take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form) question

Comment: Do you need to use each number exactly once?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: And will you use the normal rules of operator precedence? Presumably parentheses cannot be used?

Comment: Yes only one given number. Normal rules.

Comment: @brso05: I launched in with an answer based on exactly that, but the OP states 4 operands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is absolutely possible. You have to do all permutations possible for e-g there are two operands a,b and only one operator `-`. In this case possible permutations are `a-b` and `b-a`. If all permutations are done and you can't get the number, there must be a result like `number can't be arrived` (one of the possible output) from this function.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4240323/5678086) is a recursive program for doing a basic permutation. Your logic should be similar to this.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2605051/5678086) is a solution to execute your prepared expression and get the result