# How to generate permutation of different words in mapreduce?

Tags: mapreduce

How to generate permutation of different words in mapreduce using Java

```
input:abc

output:abc,acb,bac,bca,cab,cba
```

Comment: And what is code language?

Comment: Is that answer suitable for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240080/generating-all-permutations-of-a-given-string

Comment: I know the code in java but got stuck in presenting the code in map reduce..

Comment: What do you want to do? getting a word for each mapper task and convert into all permutation as a string ?

Comment: I want to get all  permutation of any given word in map reduce..

Answer (score -1):

If you know the code in java than your job is done, just put that code in Mapper and write the output to context.

In your case you will not require reducer.