# Java: Finding jumbled word

Tags: java

In my country there is Game Show called Slagalica where one of the tasks is to find longest word in array of 12 letters. Size of the longest word is always 10, 11 or 12.

I have file with words from my language I use as database. Words that have 10, 11 or 12 letters in them I've saved in List (listWordSize10_11_12).
When I enter jumbled word [12 letters] in I want from my program to find what word is that originally. I know how to make it work when jumbled word is 12 letters word but I can't work it out when it's less.

Example: 10 letter word is jumbled + 2 random letters.
Goal is  for that 10 letter word to be recognized and printed in original state.

Where is what I've done:

```
    // un-jumbling word
    System.out.println("Unesite rijec koja treba da se desifruje: ");
    String jumbledWord = tast.nextLine();
    char[] letter = jumbledWord.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(letter);
    String sorted_Mistery_Word = new String(letter);


    for (int i = 0; i < listWordSize10_11_12.size(); i++) {   
        int exception = 0;
        char[] letter_2 = listWordSize10_11_12.get(i).toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(letter_2);
        String longWords = new String(letter_2);
        int j = i;
        while(longWords.length()>i){
        if(sorted_Mistery_Word.charAt(j)!=longWords.charAt(i)){
              exception++;
              j++;
        }
        }
        if(exception < 3){
            System.out.println("Your word is: "+listWordSize10_11_12.get(i));
            break;                
        }
    }
```

Thanks!!!
P.S. This is not a homework or some job, just project I've been doing for fun!

Thanks everyone for the help, I've learned a lot!

Comment: Sounds like you want a `Map<String, String>` for (original => jumbled)

Comment: If you can do it for 12 letters, one way would be to remove a letter from the 12 and check the remaining eleven for a match. Repeat for each possible letter which can be removed out of 12 and you will have checked for all possible 11 letter words. Do something similar for 10 letter words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your basic approach for 12 characters, which I would characterize as *fingerprinting*, will also work for 10 or 11 letter words with some modification.

That is, rather that just sorting the letters in each candidate word as you examine it to create the fingerprint, pre-process your array to create a small(ish) fingerprint of each word as a `byte[]`. Using the English alphabet and ignoring case, for example, you could create a 26-byte array for each word, where each byte position contained the count of each letter in the word.

That is `fingerprint[0]` contains the number of `'a'` characters in the word, and `fingerprint[25]` the number of `'z'` characters.

Then just replace your `sorted_Mistery_Word.charAt(j)!=longWords.charAt(i)` check with a loop that increments a temporary array for each letter in the mystery word. Finally, check that the temporary array has *at least* the same value for every position. Something like:

```
byte [] makeFingerprint(String s) {
  byte[] fingerprint = new byte[26];
  for (char c : letter_2) {
    fingerprint[c - 'a']++;
  }

  return fingerprint;
}

/** determine if sub is a subset of super */
boolean isSubset(byte[] sub, byte[] super) {
  for (int i=0; i < sub.length; i++) {
    if (sub[i] > super[i]) 
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}

void findMatch(String jumbledWord) {

  byte[] fingerprint = makeFingerprint(jumbledWord);

  for (byte[] candidate : fingerprintList) {   
        if (isSubset(fingerprint, candidate)) {
            System.out.println("Your word is: " + ...);
            break;                
        }
    }
}
```

Here I omitted the creation of the `fingerprintList` - but it just involves fingerprint each word.

There are plenty of optimizations possible, but this should already be quite a bit faster than your version (and is "garbage free" in the main loop). It can handle candidates of any length (not just 10-12 chars). The biggest optimization, if you will check many words, is to try to use the "fingerpint" as a key for direct lookup. For the 12 character case this is trivial (direct lookup), but for the 10 and 11 or this you would likely have to use type of technique for higher-dimensional searching - [locality sensitive hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing) seems like a natural fit.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to go about the problem. Let's say (since no example input was provided) that there's 3 String[]'s, `arr3` (that represents the 10-letter-words you have), `arr4` (that represents the 11-letter-words you have), and `arr5` (you guessed it, represents the 12-letter words you have). This is what I made for those:

```
String[] arr3 = { "map", "cat", "dog" };
String[] arr4 = { "four", "five", "nine" };
String[] arr5 = { "funny", "comma", "brace" };
```

So based on what you said, if we got the input of `pam`, we'd want the output of `map`. If we got the input of `enni` we'd want the output of `nine`. And if we got the input of `yfunn` we'd want the output of `funny`. So how to go about doing this? I like what @cricket_007 mentioned about using maps. But first, let's get the [permutations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240080/generating-all-permutations-of-a-given-string) down.

Based off of the linked SO question, I came up with this modified/variation to get the jumbled text:

```
public static List<String> jumble(String str) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    permutation(result, "", str);
    return result;
}
private static void permutation(List<String> l, String prefix, String s) {
    int n = s.length();
    if (n == 0) {
        l.add(prefix);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            permutation(l, prefix + s.charAt(i), s.substring(0, i) + s.substring(i + 1, n));
    }
}
```

This code will let us easily construct a single map for us to store jumbled text in as a key, and the answer to that jumbled text as a value.

All together, the final code looks like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Appy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr3 = { "map", "cat", "dog" };
        String[] arr4 = { "four", "five", "nine" };
        String[] arr5 = { "funny", "comma", "brace" };
        List<String> permutations = new ArrayList<String>();
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (String s : arr3) {
            permutations = jumble(s);
            for (String str : permutations)
                map.put(str, s);
        }
        for (String s : arr4) {
            permutations = jumble(s);
            for (String str : permutations)
                map.put(str, s);
        }
        for (String s : arr5) {
            permutations = jumble(s);
            for (String str : permutations)
                map.put(str, s);
        }
        System.out.println("test = 'pam' -> " + map.get("pam"));
        System.out.println("test = 'enni' -> " + map.get("enni"));
        System.out.println("test = 'yfunn' -> " + map.get("yfunn"));
    }
    public static List<String> jumble(String str) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        permutation(result, "", str);
        return result;
    }
    private static void permutation(List<String> l, String prefix, String s) {
        int n = s.length();
        if (n == 0) {
            l.add(prefix);
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                permutation(l, prefix + s.charAt(i), s.substring(0, i) + s.substring(i + 1, n));
        }
    }
}
```

Which gives the resulting output of:

```
test = 'pam' -> map
test = 'enni' -> nine
test = 'yfunn' -> funny
```

Now applying this logic, adapting for your case of 10, 11, and 12 letter words should be relatively simple. Cheers!

Comment: A permutation-based approach will create an explosive number of possibilities. For example, there are `12! = ~500,000,000` permutations of a 12-character String. So _every single string_ of 12 characters will take ~1GB of memory just to store the permutations. With a modest dictionary size of say even 1,000 words, you better have a supercomputer-size amount of RAM to store that list.

Comment: This is true, the trade-offs quickly grow here. Good point to mention because I didn't account for that initially using the small subset example.