# Print unique numbers

Tags: java

I am trying to print all unique possibilities of 1 2 3 4 5 with + - * /
One would look like 1+2-3*4/5
Another possibility would have the numbers rearranged or operations rearranged. I thought my mistake was an infinite loop, but it prints the final term 47 at the end. Please help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] all = new int[47];

        System.out.print(all.length);

        int b = 0;

        int c = 0;
        for (int count = 0; count < 47;) {

            int num1 = (int) (Math.random() * 5 + 1);

            int num2 = num1;

            while (num2 == num1) {
                num2 = (int) (Math.random() * 5 + 1);
            }

            int num3 = num2;

            while ((num3 == num1) || (num3 == num2)) {
                num3 = (int) (Math.random() * 5 + 1);

            }

            int num4 = num3;

            while ((num4 == num1) || (num4 == num2) || (num4 == num3)) {
                num4 = (int) (Math.random() * 5 + 1);
            }

            int num5 = num4;

            while ((num5 == num1) || (num5 == num2) || (num5 == num3) || (num5 == num4)) {
                num5 = (int) (Math.random() * 5 + 1);
            }

            int numbers1 = num1 + num2 - num3 * num4 / num5;

            for (int i = 0; i < all.length; i++)

            {
                if (all[i] == numbers1) {
                    b = 1;
                }

                if ((b != 1) && (i == (all.length - 1))) {
                    all[count] = numbers1;
                    count++;
                }

            }
            int numbers2 = num1 + num2 - num3 / num4 * num5;

            for (int i = 0; i < all.length; i++)

            {
                if (all[i] == numbers2) {
                    b = 1;
                }

                if ((b != 1) && (i == (all.length - 1))) {
                    all[count] = numbers2;
                    count++;
                }
            }
            int numbers3 = num1 + num2 / num3 - num4 * num5;

            for (int i = 0; i < all.length; i++)

            {
                if (all[i] == numbers3) {
                    b = 1;
                }

                if ((b != 1) && (i == (all.length - 1))) {
                    all[count] = numbers3;
                    count++;
                }
            }
            int numbers4 = num1 + num2 / num3 * num4 - num5;

            for (int i = 0; i < all.length; i++)

            {
                if (all[i] == numbers4) {
                    b = 1;
                }

                if ((b != 1) && (i == (all.length - 1))) {
                    all[count] = numbers4;
                    count++;
                }
            }

            int numbers5 = num1 + num2 * num3 / num4 - num5;

            for (int i = 0; i < all.length; i++)

            {
                if (all[i] == numbers5) {
                    b = 1;
                }

                if ((b != 1) && (i == (all.length - 1))) {
                    all[count] = numbers5;
                    count++;
                }
            }
            int numbers6 = num1 + num2 * num3 - num4 / num5;

            for (int i = 0; i < all.length; i++)

            {
                if (all[i] == numbers6) {
                    b = 1;
                }

                if ((b != 1) && (i == (all.length - 1))) {
                    all[count] = numbers6;
                    count++;
                }
            }
            int numbers7 = num1 - num2 + num3 / num4 * num5;

            for (int i = 0; i < all.length; i++)

            {
                if (all[i] == numbers7) {
                    b = 1;
                }

                if ((b != 1) && (i == (all.length - 1))) {
                    all[count] = numbers7;
                    count++;
                }
            }

            int numbers8 = num1 - num2 + num3 * num4 / num5;

            for (int i = 0; i < all.length; i++)

            {
                if (all[i] == numbers8) {
                    b = 1;
                }

                if ((b != 1) && (i == (all.length - 1))) {
                    all[count] = numbers8;
                    count++;
                }
            }

            int numbers9 = num1 - num2 / num3 + num4 * num5;

            for (int i = 0; i < all.length; i++)

            {
                if (all[i] == numbers9) {
                    b = 1;
                }

                if ((b != 1) && (i == (all.length - 1))) {
                    all[count] = numbers9;
                    count++;
                }
            }
            int numbers10 = num1 - num2 / num3 * num4 + num5;

            for (int i = 0; i < all.length; i++)

            {
                if (all[i] == numbers10) {
                    b = 1;
                }

                if ((b != 1) && (i == (all.length - 1))) {
                    all[count] = numbers10;
                    count++;
                }
            }
            int numbers11 = num1 - num2 * num3 / num4 + num5;

            for (int i = 0; i < all.length; i++)

            {
                if (all[i] == numbers11) {
                    b = 1;
                }

                if ((b != 1) && (i == (all.length - 1))) {
                    all[count] = numbers11;
                    count++;
                }
            }
            int numbers12 = num1 - num2 * num3 + num4 / num5;

            for (int i = 0; i < all.length; i++)

            {
                if (all[i] == numbers12) {
                    b = 1;
                }

                if ((b != 1) && (i == (all.length - 1))) {
                    all[count] = numbers12;
                    count++;
                }
            }

            int numbers13 = num1 / num2 * num3 - num4 + num5;

            for (int i = 0; i < all.length; i++)

            {
                if (all[i] == numbers13) {
                    b = 1;
                }

                if ((b != 1) && (i == (all.length - 1))) {
                    all[count] = numbers13;
                    count++;
                }
            }
            int numbers14 = num1 / num2 * num3 + num4 - num5;

            for (int i = 0; i < all.length; i++)

            {
                if (all[i] == numbers14) {
                    b = 1;
                }

                if ((b != 1) && (i == (all.length - 1))) {
                    all[count] = numbers14;
                    count++;
                }
            }
            int numbers15 = num1 / num2 + num3 * num4 - num5;

            for (int i = 0; i < all.length; i++)

            {
                if (all[i] == numbers15) {
                    b = 1;
                }

                if ((b != 1) && (i == (all.length - 1))) {
                    all[count] = numbers15;
                    count++;
                }
            }
            int numbers16 = num1 / num2 + num3 - num4 * num5;

            for (int i = 0; i < all.length; i++)

            {
                if (all[i] == numbers16) {
                    b = 1;
                }

                if ((b != 1) && (i == (all.length - 1))) {
                    all[count] = numbers16;
                    count++;
                }
            }
            int numbers17 = num1 / num2 - num3 * num4 + num5;

            for (int i = 0; i < all.length; i++)

            {
                if (all[i] == numbers17) {
                    b = 1;
                }

                if ((b != 1) && (i == (all.length - 1))) {
                    all[count] = numbers17;
                    count++;
                }
            }
            int numbers18 = num1 / num2 - num3 + num4 * num5;

            for (int i = 0; i < all.length; i++)

            {
                if (all[i] == numbers18) {
                    b = 1;
                }

                if ((b != 1) && (i == (all.length - 1))) {
                    all[count] = numbers18;
                    count++;
                }
            }
            int numbers19 = num1 * num2 / num3 - num4 + num5;

            for (int i = 0; i < all.length; i++)

            {
                if (all[i] == numbers19) {
                    b = 1;
                }

                if ((b != 1) && (i == (all.length - 1))) {
                    all[count] = numbers19;
                    count++;
                }
            }
            int numbers20 = num1 * num2 / num3 + num4 - num5;

            for (int i = 0; i < all.length; i++)

            {
                if (all[i] == numbers20) {
                    b = 1;
                }

                if ((b != 1) && (i == (all.length - 1))) {
                    all[count] = numbers20;
                    count++;
                }
            }
            int numbers21 = num1 * num2 + num3 - num4 / num5;

            for (int i = 0; i < all.length; i++)

            {
                if (all[i] == numbers21) {
                    b = 1;
                }

                if ((b != 1) && (i == (all.length - 1))) {
                    all[count] = numbers21;
                    count++;
                }
            }

            int numbers22 = num1 * num2 + num3 / num4 - num5;

            for (int i = 0; i < all.length; i++)

            {
                if (all[i] == numbers22) {
                    b = 1;
                }

                if ((b != 1) && (i == (all.length - 1))) {
                    all[count] = numbers22;
                    count++;
                }
            }

            int numbers23 = num1 * num2 - num3 / num4 + num5;

            for (int i = 0; i < all.length; i++)

            {
                if (all[i] == numbers23) {
                    b = 1;
                }

                if ((b != 1) && (i == (all.length - 1))) {
                    all[count] = numbers23;
                    count++;
                }
            }
            int numbers24 = num1 * num2 - num3 + num4 / num5;

            for (int i = 0; i < all.length; i++)

            {
                if (all[i] == numbers24) {
                    b = 1;
                }

                if ((b != 1) && (i == (all.length - 1))) {
                    all[count] = numbers24;
                    count++;
                }
            }

        }

        for (c = 0; c < all.length; c++) {
            if (c > 0) {
                System.out.print(", ");
            }
            System.out.print(all[c]);

        }
        System.out.print(all.length);

    }

}
```

Comment: You need to post less code. This is far too much to expect anyone to dig through. Did you try debugging it?

Answer (score 0):

Your "final" term 47 gets printed as third row in main method before loops start. Because you are printing length of the all array.

System.out.print(all.length);

About the code itself. Your best bet is to reduce number of your loops. This is pointless complexity as every loop inside of your main loop will be run 47 times. For suggestions on how to fix the algorithm take a look at other questions regarding the combinations/permutations. For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240080/generating-all-permutations-of-a-given-string).