# I can't correctly calculate the permutations of a number

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

help, I made a code that allows to calculate the permutations of a number. for example if I enter the number 2090, this returns me the solutions:
2090, 0092, 0290, 0209, 9200, 9002, 9020, 0029, 0920, 0902, 2900, 2009, 2090, 0092, 0290, 0209, 9200, 9002, 9020, 0029, 0920, 0902, 2900, 2009.

then filter the solutions so that they are multiple of 11, have no zeros left and do not repeat. this filter gives me if I use the same number (2090) the following solutions:

2090
9020

here is where I have the problem, if I enter for example the number 2900 should give me the same solutions as when entering 2090, but I only return a solution that is 9020
How can I fix this error?

this is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a Number");
        String n = read.next();

        //Calculate number of permutations
        long nPer = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n.length(); i++) {
            nPer *= i;

        }
        System.out.println("Number of Permutations:" + nPer);
        char nums[] = n.toCharArray();

        //performs the permutation of the number according to the number of permutations
        for (int i = 0; i < nPer; i++) {

            /*
            valid if it is multiple of 11, does not have 0 to the left or if it is repeated and adds it to the ArrayList called list
             */

            if (Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(nums)) % 11 == 0) {
                if (nums[0] != '0') {
                    if (!list.contains(String.valueOf(nums))) {
                        list.add(String.valueOf(nums));
                    }
                }
            }

            char t = nums[i % (nums.length - 1)];
            nums[i % (nums.length - 1)] = nums[nums.length - 1];
            nums[nums.length - 1] = t;

        }
        //Display list with final solutions
        System.out.println("______________");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println(list.size());

    }
```

Comment: Debug your program, it is not generating correct permutations. it never generates `2090` in second input of `2900`

Comment: mm, you're right, I think the method that calculates the permutation is bad, but it's the only way I can think of, any ideas?

Comment: Google it , you will surely get many :)

Comment: many, such as here on SO: [Generating all permutations of a given string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4240080/17300)

Answer (score 0):

Here is why posting [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is so helpful:
When you eliminate the filters :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String n = "2900";
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    //Calculate number of permutations
    long nPer = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n.length(); i++) {
        nPer *= i;
    }

    char nums[] = n.toCharArray();

    //performs the permutation of the number according to the number of permutations
    for (int i = 0; i < nPer; i++) {

        list.add(String.valueOf(nums));

        char t = nums[i % (nums.length - 1)];
        nums[i % (nums.length - 1)] = nums[nums.length - 1];
        nums[nums.length - 1] = t;
    }
    //Display list with final solutions

    System.out.println("______________");
    for (String s:  list) { System.out.println(s); }       
}
```

You get:

> 2900 0902 0209 0290 0290 0092 0029 9020 9020 9002 2009 2900 2900 0902
>   0209 0290 0290 0092 0029 9020 9020 9002 2009 2900

As you can see `2090` combination is not generated. On the other hands, other combinations appear more than once. 
So now it is very clear that you need to look into:

```
        char t = nums[i % (nums.length - 1)];
        nums[i % (nums.length - 1)] = nums[nums.length - 1];
        nums[nums.length - 1] = t;
```

(Always verify that a piece of code works as expected, before adding complexity) 
To properly find permutations, try:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(permutation(n));

private static Set<String>  permutation(String s) {

    if((s == null) || (s.length() < 2) ) {
        return null;
    }

    Set<String> permutations = new HashSet<>();
    permutation(0,s,permutations);
    return permutations;
}

private static void  permutation(int index, String s, Set<String> permutations) {

    permutations.add(s);

    if(index >= (s.length()-1)) {
        return;
    }

    char[] chars = s.toCharArray();

    for(int pos=0; pos < s.length() ; pos++) {

        char[] temp  = s.toCharArray();

        char c = temp[pos];
        temp[pos] = chars[index];
        temp[index] = c;

        permutation(index +1, String.valueOf(temp),  permutations);
    }

}
```