# Given a set of inputs and a result, how would I get the equation used to get the result?

Tags: java, math

I looked through here and found questions similar but not solving for the equation. Here is what I'm looking to do. I need to be able to determine a collection of equations that potentially can be used to solve a set of input parameters and a result. I will always know the inputs and the results. I need to figure out a way to solve for the solution for lack of a better term.

For instance:

Input parameters: 5,1,1,2

Result: 8

I would like to input these numbers and result and get something like:

FirstNumber(5) * (SecondNumber(1) + ThirdNumber(1)) - FourthNumber(2) = 8

FirstNumber(5) * FourthNumber(2) - SecondNumber(1) - ThirdNumber(1) = 8

Obviously it can be complex and given more numbers could have many possible solutions. My general question is around feasibility.

Comment: Are you limited to +,-,*? Do you always have the same number of input parameters?

Comment: No, input parameters can change in quantity but for the most part the equation should be +,-,*,/.

Comment: Do you have to use all the available numbers, or can you leave some unused?

Comment: All numbers will be used.

Comment: Here's a **rough solution outline**.  Iterate through the numbers.  For each number, recurse four times, to find expressions to fit `number + ( expression ) = result`, `number * ( expression ) = result`, `number - ( expression ) = result` and `( expression ) - number = result`, where in each case `expression` is found recursively using the inputs _without_ the current number, and a different value for `result`.  You'd only include the one with the `*` if `result % number == 0`.

Answer (score 3):

It is actually quite difficult task to solve.

First - you have to be able to solve any equation with `+-*/` and with `()`. How to do that? You have to create tree-like structure with these operators and be able to count the result.

If you visualize the tree it looks like this: [image: Tree]

When you are finished with this task, you can start with generating all the possibilities that can happen. The [Backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) is actually quite useful, as it is automatically remove the paths that does not lead to anything and with proper implementation it finds all possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

To get a collection of all possible linear equations I would try permutation without repetition for the inputs except the result (ignore possible identical inputs)   and permutation taken from each cobination of all operators taken G at a time where G is the number of gaps between input numbers  to fill the gaps between numbers and then try every position and size more than one and less than N for the numbers inside of the "()" where N is the number of inputs excluding the result.
Check the answers in this link for how to get permutation in java 
[Generating all permutations of a given string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240080/generating-all-permutations-of-a-given-string)