# I need get specific url, but i don't know all signs in url

Tags: java, url

I need get specific url with start : "nbp.pl/kursy/xml/c" and ending "z070413.xml"
Between c and z is 3 numbers from 0 to 9. How can i get all this urls ?

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4240323/2266098

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following regex pattern:

```
^nbp\.pl/kursy/xml/c[0-9]{3}z070413\.xml$
```

Sample Java code:

```
String url = "nbp.pl/kursy/xml/c123z070413.xml";
if (url.matches("nbp\\.pl/kursy/xml/c[0-9]{3}z070413\\.xml")) {
    System.out.println("URL is a match");
}
```

The three digits in between the `c` and `z` is represented by `[0-9]{3}`, and also literal dot `\.` needs to be escaped in the regex using a backslash.