# Create strings to multi relation keywords

Tags: php, arrays, string, search, split

I need to create an Array of multi relation keywords from string for search terms.
Example:
String is Like: Armitage Portable Wireless Powerbank with Suction

I need an Output Like

```
1) Armitage
2) Portable
3) Wireless
4) Powerbank
5) Suction
6) Armitage Portable
7) Armitage Wireless
8) Armitage Powerbank
9) Armitage Suction
10) Portable Wireless
11) Portable Powerbank
12) Portable Suction
13) Wireless Powerbank
14) Wireless Suction
15) Powerbank Suction
16) Armitage Portable Wireless
17) Armitage Portable Powerbank
18) Armitage Portable Suction
```

Etc...

Comment: So you want to create _permutations_. Use that as a (re-)search keyword, please, you are by far not the first person ever to ask for something like this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating all permutations of a given string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240080/generating-all-permutations-of-a-given-string)

Comment: No, I need that in PHP, I need to split with words not with characters.

Comment: Thanks I Implemented that logic and it working Fine.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using the example below:

`explode(" ", $string)`