# How could you generate all permutations of ABC with no repeats for any length?

Tags: java, list, loops, set, iteration

So if I had a list of

String[] list = {A,B,C};
generateAllCombonations(list);

would return:
ABC
ACB
BAC
BCA
CAB
CBA

for any length of the list?
AAB would not be allowed given no repeats
also, AB would be invalid because it is not the length of the original array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240080/generating-all-permutations-of-a-given-string

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.