# Can this algorithm be optimised?

Tags: algorithm

I have a list of some objects and I want to iterate through them in a specific sequence for a particular number as returned by the following function. What the following does is, removes each number based on the modulo of the hash number to the list size and generates a sequence.

```
def genSeq(hash,n):
    l = range(n)
    seq = []
    while l:
        ind = hash % len(l)
        seq.append(l[ind])
        del l[ind]
    return seq
```

Eg: genSeq(53,5) will return `[3, 1, 4, 2, 0]`

I am presenting the algo in python for easy understanding. I am supposed to code in c++. The complexity in this form in O(n^2) both for vector and list. (we either pay for removing or for access). Can this be made any better ?

Comment: Using an appropriate datastructure for your `l` theoretically a `log n` performance is possible which would then be `n log n` in total. Nevertheless I doubt that this performance gain is big unless your `n` is really large.

Comment: so, you want to shuffle n numbers, right ?

Comment: which datastructure would be suitable? How is it log n?

Comment: @Zonko yes. but in a sequence based on a argument(hash)

Comment: @balki For example with a balanced binary tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) would give you `O(log n)` access and removal. So your total traversal time would be `O(n log n)`.

I'd like to think there is a linear solution, but nothing jumps out at me.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence
    [hash % (i+1) in range(len(l))]
can be seen as a number in [factoradic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system).
There is a bijection between permutations and factoradic numbers.

The mapping from factoradic numbers to permutations is described in [the top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506078/fast-permutation-number-permutation-mapping-algorithms) under the section "Permuting a list using an index sequence". Unfortunately the algorithm provided is quadratic. However there is a commenter which points to a data-structure which would make the algorithm O(nlog(n)).

Answer (score -1):

You should not delete from your vector, but swap with the end and decrease a fill pointer.  Think about the Fisher-Yates shuffle.

Comment: That's not going to work because it will change the order of items. You wouldn't get the same order as if you used his algorithm.