# Check if permutations of characters are contained in text file

Tags: c#, permutation

Quick question.
I am writing a program to find all the permutations of a set of characters I input into the application.
This part works perfectly.
My problem is that I need to check all the permutations of the characters against a text file I use as a dictionary. 
Ex. If I input the characters TSTE the outputs givin are tset,ttse,ttes,tets,test,stte,stet,sett...
I only want to print the valid words like tset,sett,stet,test,tets. where ttse,ttes,stte is not printed.

The code I have so far is as follows.
I have been scracthing at the edges of my scull for the past few days and just cant seem to find a way to do it.
Please if there is anything you can see that I have missed?

Thank you

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.BufferHeight = Int16.MaxValue - 1;

            Console.WindowHeight = 40;
            Console.WindowWidth = 120;

            Permute p = new Permute();            
            var d = Read();
            string line;
            string str = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Dictionary.txt");
            while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
            {                
                char[] c2 = line.ToArray();                
                p.setper(c2);
                           }
        }
        static Dictionary<string, string> Read()
        {
            var d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Dictionary.txt"))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string a = Alphabet(line);
                    string v;
                    if (d.TryGetValue(a, out v))
                    {
                        d[a] = v + "," + line;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        d.Add(a, line);
                    }
                }
            }
            return d;
        }
        static string Alphabet(string s)
        {
            char[] a = s.ToCharArray();
            Array.Sort(a);
            return new string(a);
        }
        static void Show(Dictionary<string, string> d, string w)
        {
            string v;
            if (d.TryGetValue(Alphabet(w), out v))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(v);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("-----------");
            }
        }
    }
    class Permute
    {
        private void swap(ref char a, ref char b)
        {
            if (a == b) return;
            a ^= b;
            b ^= a;
            a ^= b;
        }
        public void setper(char[] list)
        {
            int x = list.Length - 1;
            go(list, 0, x);
        }
        public void go(char[] list1, int k, int m)
        {
            if (k == m)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(list1);
                Console.WriteLine(" ");

            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = k; i <= m; i++)
                {
                    swap(ref list1[k], ref list1[i]);
                    go(list1, k + 1, m);
                    swap(ref list1[k], ref list1[i]);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your sample is hard to follow. Please remove all reading from files/console (hardcode all values), make clear `HashSet<string>` (or `Dictionary<string, bool>`) dictionary of words. Consider extracting generation of all permutations as IEnumerable<string>....

Comment: Might be easier to follow if you renamed some of your variables (and methods) to something closer to English words representing their purposes For instance `permutationProvider` instead of `p, `dictionaryWords` instead of `str`. Also, what does `Go()` mean? (Go where? ;) ) How about renaming it to something like `CheckEqualityRecursively()`, or something else a little more descriptive?

Answer (score 0):

you just missed    Show(d, line); i loop.

change like this.

```
while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            char[] c2 = line.ToArray();
            p.setper(c2);
            Console.WriteLine(" combinations which are in Dictionary are:");
            Show(d, line);

        }
```

then ..
you didn't required dictionary

```
  use List<string> Dic=new List<string>();// declare it in globally

  Dic.add(line); //each line in dictionary
```

before printing each word

```
 if(Dic.contains(word))
   print it; 
 else{ //no printing }
```

Comment: Kent Kin answer also right no need to permute it. U just call Show(d, line); if your dictionary has all valid words.

Comment: Yes that,s great thanks. I have tried that option before, the problem is not that it does not work. My problem is that I need to use the permutation version of this because i intend to use this program for finding permutations for inputs with spaces as well as single words. The matching to the multiple words in the dictionary is something that I will figure out a bit later on.

Comment: i'm not get what you say could you ex-plane it with some example. what the actual requirement is?

Comment: As in the initial example where I used TSTE I would at the end like to use this program with inputs like TSTE POGRMA which utilizes more than one word in the input and then the output should be more like this: TEST PROGRAM. Does that help a bit more?

Comment: Are you searching replacement of misspelled words using dictionary?

Comment: Basically yes. If the permutation is contained in the Dictionary file I want it to be displayed. if not contained it should not be displayed

Comment: Thanks I'll see what it does

Comment: I'm baffled why you'd suggest changing a `Dictionary` to a `List` when it comes to searching a very large collection for strings a very large number of times.  Lists are *terrible* at searching compared to a dictionary or other hash based data structure.

Comment: ok i got you, now you use dictionary like <string,int/bool> string is word in dictionary and key value your wish the first code works with you.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with current state.

It's possible because

1. If the "dictionary.txt" was your input, then you did not define what are the *valid words*. 
   You at leaset need another dictionary to define those *valid words* or an algorithm to decide what those are and what those are not.
2. If the input is from UI and "dictionary.txt" is the defined *valid words*, you don't need to the permute the input, just search the input from "dictionary.txt".

However, your `Read` method is improvable, like

```
static Dictionary<String, String> Read(String path) {
    return (
        from line in File.ReadAllLines(path)
        where false==String.IsNullOrEmpty(line)
        group line by Alphabet(line) into g
        select
            new {
                Value=String.Join(",", g.ToArray()),
                Key=g.Key
            }
        ).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although for the *valid words* are as I mentioned in another answer, not possible with your current state, I've make the code pretty clear for you.

It finally the code, is separated in three parts. They are `Permutable<T>`, `ConsoleHelper` and the `ConsoleApplication1.Program` with an utility `Permutation` class.

- Permutable<T> (Permutable.cs)

  ```
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Collections;
  using System;

  public partial class Permutable<T>: IEnumerable {
      public static explicit operator Permutable<T>(T[] array) {
          return new Permutable<T>(array);
      }

      static IEnumerable Permute<TElement>(IList<TElement> list, int depth, int count) {
          if(count==depth)
              yield return list;
          else {
              for(var i=depth; i<=count; ++i) {
                  Swap(list, depth, i);

                  foreach(var sequence in Permutable<T>.Permute(list, 1+depth, count))
                      yield return sequence;

                  Swap(list, depth, i);
              }
          }
      }

      static void Swap<TElement>(IList<TElement> list, int depth, int index) {
          var local=list[depth];
          list[depth]=list[index];
          list[index]=local;
      }

      IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
          return this.GetEnumerator();
      }

      public IEnumerator<IList<T>> GetEnumerator() {
          var list=this.m_List;

          if(list.Count>0)
              foreach(IList<T> sequence in Permutable<T>.Permute(list, 0, list.Count-1))
                  yield return sequence;
      }

      protected Permutable(IList<T> list) {
          this.m_List=list;
      }

      IList<T> m_List;
  }
  ```
- ConsoleHelper (ConsoleHelper.cs)

  ```
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
  using System.Windows.Forms;
  using System.Drawing;

  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;

  public static partial class ConsoleHelper {
      [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
      public struct RECT {
          public static explicit operator Rectangle(RECT rect) {
              return new Rectangle {
                  X=rect.Left,
                  Y=rect.Top,
                  Width=rect.Right-rect.Left,
                  Height=rect.Bottom-rect.Top
              };
          }

          public int Left;
          public int Top;
          public int Right;
          public int Bottom;
      }

      [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
      static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int Width, int Height, bool repaint);

      [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
      static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT rect);

      [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
      static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

      public static void CenterScreen() {
          RECT rect;
          var hWnn=ConsoleHelper.GetConsoleWindow();
          var workingArea=Screen.GetWorkingArea(Point.Empty);
          ConsoleHelper.GetWindowRect(hWnn, out rect);
          var rectangle=(Rectangle)rect;

          rectangle=
             new Rectangle {
                 X=(workingArea.Width-rectangle.Width)/2,
                 Y=(workingArea.Height-rectangle.Height)/2,
                 Width=rectangle.Width,
                 Height=rectangle.Height
             };

          ConsoleHelper.MoveWindow(
              hWnn,
              rectangle.Left, rectangle.Top, rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height,
              true
              );
      }
  }
  ```
- ConsoleApplication1.Program & Permutation (Program.cs)

  ```
  using System.Collections;
  using System.IO;

  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;

  public partial class Permutation {
      public static Permutation FromFile(String path) {
          return new Permutation(path);
      }

      public static String GetSortedAlphabet(String text) {
          var array=text.ToArray();
          Array.Sort(array);
          return new String(array);
      }

      public Dictionary<String, String> Dictionary {
          private set;
          get;
      }

      public FileInfo SourceFile {
          private set;
          get;
      }

      public Permutation(String path) {
          this.Dictionary=(
              from line in File.ReadAllLines(path)
              where false==String.IsNullOrEmpty(line)
              group line by Permutation.GetSortedAlphabet(line) into g
              select
                  new {
                      Value=String.Join(", ", g.Distinct().ToArray()),
                      Key=g.Key
                  }
              ).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

          this.SourceFile=new FileInfo(path);
      }
  }

  namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
      partial class Program {
          static void ProcessLine(IList<char> input) {
              Console.WriteLine();

              if(input.Count>0) {
                  var inputArray=input.ToArray();
                  var key=Permutation.GetSortedAlphabet(new String(inputArray));
                  var dict=Program.Permutation.Dictionary;
                  var hasKey=dict.ContainsKey(key);
                  var source=Permutation.SourceFile;

                  Console.WriteLine("Possible permutations are: ");

                  foreach(var sequence in (Permutable<char>)inputArray)
                      Console.WriteLine("{0}", new String(sequence.ToArray()));

                  Console.WriteLine("Acceptable in file '{0}' are: ", source.FullName);
                  Console.WriteLine("{0}", hasKey?dict[key]:"<none>");
                  Console.WriteLine();

                  input.Clear();
              }

              Console.Write(Prompt);
          }

          static void ProcessChar(IList<char> input, char keyChar) {
              Console.Write(keyChar);
              input.Add(keyChar);
          }

          static void ProcessExit(IList<char> input, char keyChar) {
              Console.WriteLine();
              Console.Write("Are you sure to exit? (Press Esc again to exit)");
              input.Add(keyChar);
          }

          static bool ProcessLast(IList<char> input, char keyChar) {
              var last=input.Count-1;

              if(0>last||input[last]!=(char)ConsoleKey.Escape)
                  return false;

              input.Clear();
              return true;
          }

          public static Permutation Permutation {
              private set;
              get;
          }

          public static String Prompt {
              private set;
              get;
          }
      }

      partial class Program {
          static void Main(String[] args) {
              Console.BufferHeight=short.MaxValue-1;
              Console.SetWindowSize(120, 40);
              ConsoleHelper.CenterScreen();

              var input=new List<char>(char.MaxValue);
              Program.Permutation=Permutation.FromFile(@"c:\dictionary.txt");
              Program.Prompt="User>\x20";
              Program.ProcessLine(input);

              for(; ; ) {
                  var keyInfo=Console.ReadKey(true);
                  var keyChar=keyInfo.KeyChar;
                  var keyCode=keyInfo.Key;

                  if(ConsoleKey.Escape==keyCode) {
                      if(Program.ProcessLast(input, keyChar))
                          break;

                      Program.ProcessExit(input, keyChar);
                      continue;
                  }

                  if(ConsoleKey.Enter==keyCode) {
                      Program.ProcessLine(input);
                      continue;
                  }

                  if(default(ConsoleModifiers)!=keyInfo.Modifiers)
                      continue;

                  if(0x1f>keyChar||keyChar>0x7f)
                      continue;

                  if(Program.ProcessLast(input, keyChar))
                      Console.WriteLine();

                  Program.ProcessChar(input, keyChar);
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

The `ConsoleHelper` class is only use for ceteral your resized console window, that you can test the program more comfortable. The `Permutable` class is what I fully re-designed from your original class; it now come with `IEnumerable` to permute, and also a generic class.

The `Permutation` class, is like a utility class, itself provide a `FromFile` method as your original `Read`, and stores the `Dictionary<String, String>` as a property. The original method `Alphabet` is renamed `GetSortedAlphabet` for more semantical.

The `Program` class has four main static `ProcessXXX` methods, they are

- ProcessChar: processes for a `char` of the range from `0x20` to `0x7f`
- ProcessLine: processes for `Enter` pressed
- ProcessExit: processes for `Excape` pressed
- ProcessLast: additional processing for `ProcessLine` and `ProcessExit`

Yes, I meant to make them have the same length of name. For more, `Program` class have two static properties; `Permutation` for storing a instance of class `Permutation`, and `Prompt` is a string for prompting user.

When your input is not defined in `"c:\dictionary.txt"`, the prompt of `"Acceptable in file .."` will get you `"<none>"`.

The exit command is twice-Escape key press, you would see

> Are you sure to exit? (Press Esc again to exit)

and if you press `Enter` or other keys, it back to the initial state.

That's all. Now it's time to discover the finally problem you've encountered. After you test with this program, you might describe you questions and issues more clearly.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your feedback. 
I have finally figured it out and found a solution to the problem I was having.
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.BufferHeight = Int16.MaxValue - 1;

```
        Console.WindowHeight = 40;
        Console.WindowWidth = 120;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your caracters for the anagram: ");
        //var d = Read();
        string line;
        //string DictionaryInput = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Dictionary.txt");
        while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your results are: ");
            char[] charArray = line.ToArray();
            //Show(d, line);                    //Using this to check that words found are the correct words in the dictionary.
            setper(charArray);
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------DONE-----------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your caracters for the anagram: ");
            File.Delete("Permutations.txt");
        }

    }



    static void swap(ref char a, ref char b)
    {
        if (a == b) return;
        a ^= b;
        b ^= a;
        a ^= b;
    }
    static void setper(char[] list)
    {
        int x = list.Length - 1;
        permuteWords(list, 0, x);
    }
    static void permuteWords(char[] list1, int k, int m)
    {

        if (k == m)
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Permutations.txt", true);
            sw.WriteLine(list1);
            sw.Close();
            Regex permutationPattern = new Regex(new string(list1));
            string[] permutations = File.ReadAllLines("Permutations.txt");
            Regex pattern = new Regex(new string(list1));
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("Dictionary.txt");

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                var matches = pattern.Matches(line);
                if (pattern.ToString() == line)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = k; i <= m; i++)
            {
                swap(ref list1[k], ref list1[i]);
                permuteWords(list1, k + 1, m);
                swap(ref list1[k], ref list1[i]);
            }
        }


    }
```