# How to compress a sequence of non-repeated number size N bits?

Tags: c++, algorithm, compression

Im trying to compress a sequence of non-negative numbers, where:

- The value range of each number is from 0 to 2^N-1
- Each number appears once only (it means there is total 2^N numbers )

  Example for N = 4:

  [14, 1, 8, 2, 12, 6, 0, 10, 4, 13, 5, 7, 15, 9, 3, 11]

So normally each number will cost 4 bits and for 16 numbers we will have to use 16x4 = 64 bits to store them.

Currently I have just thought of compressing them as below:

- For the first 8 numbers --> use 4 bits to store each of them.
- For the next 4 numbers ---> only 3 bits/each
- For the next 2 numbers ---> only 2 bits/each
- For the next 1 numbers ---> only 1 bit for it.
- For the last one, actually its not necesssary to be stored (Obviously we should know what the last number is if we know all other 15 numbers )

So the compressed data size will be:

```
Z = 8 * 4 + 4 * 3 + 2 * 2 + 1 * 1 + 1 * 0 = 49 bits
```

The compression ratio is about 76%, which is pretty good (I think).

But for larger values of N, the ratio seems to be decreased (For N = 2048, the ratio is only 91% )

So I would like to hear your suggestions for better compressing.

Thank you.

Comment: As you've tagged your question [tag:c++], would you mind showing a small sample of your implementation approach? It might be relevant for the worse compression ratios.

Comment: Does preserving original order matter?

Comment: @jdphenix: yes, it is very important.

Comment: @jdphenix the original order seems to be the only information being compressed here.

Comment: @jdphenix: I think that's exactly what matters.  Each number only appears exactly once.

Comment: Since you use every possible number once, I think the most entropy would be in something **similar to** storing a single number that describes the number of calls to [`std::next_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) that would transform a sorted list to your result.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089078/encode-order-of-playing-cards-data-compression

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ: Thank you. Actually i have not made any implement yet. But my idea is very simple, so the compressed size will always be able to calculated , and it will not get impact by the implementation aproach.

Comment: You could improve compression using [phased-in codes](http://www.davidsalomon.name/VLCadvertis/phasedin.pdf).

Comment: This doesn't make good use of "fractional bits", you could use the same thing but with range-coding to improve it.

Comment: @harold Very correct - when there is only 3 items remaining, each has a 33% change of being the next number.  1/3 doesn't perfectly translate to a bit count and therefore range coding vs a huffman like technique will save you some space.

Comment: Going from 49-bits where you are now to 45-bits seems like, well, quite a bit of work.  Even at 8-bits where the below formulas give a best case of 1684 bits, your solution will give 1792 bits - only ~10% off the maximum.  Considering that you are going to need to code an arithmetic encoder to get closer to maximum, perhaps you stick with what you have.

Comment: You just have permutation, and you needed encode permutation number. See detailed answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506078/fast-permutation-number-permutation-mapping-algorithms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is pointed out in comments, the optimal encoding -- if all permutations are equally probable -- is to replace the entire permutation with its index in the enumeration of permutations. Since there are *n*! possible permutations, the index requires log<sub>2</sub>*n*! bits, and therefore the compression ratio from the naive encoding using log<sub>2</sub>*n* bits for each element is (log *n*!)/(*n* log *n*).

Using [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), we can rewrite that as (*n* log *n* - *n* + O(log *n*))/(*n* log *n*), which is 1 - 1/(log *n*) + O(1/*n*) which evidently asymptotically approaches 1 as *n* grows. So it is inevitable that the compression ratio will decrease for larger *n*.

It is not possible to achieve better compression unless not all permutations are equally probable (and you have some information about the probability distribution).

Answer (score 2):

For this specific problem, the most efficient encoding is to view the permutation of `[0 .. 2^N-1]` as a numeral in the [factorial number system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system) and store the [Lehmer code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_code) for that permutation.

This gives a requirement of `ceil(log2((2^N)!))` bits. For N = 4, this uses 45 bits (70.3%); for N = 11 (2^N = 2048), 19581 bits (86.9%).

The compression ratio worsens as N increases; using the simple approximation `log x! >= (x log x) - x + 1` we attain a minimum for `log2((2^N)!) / (N 2^N)` of `1 - ((2^N - 1)/(2^N))*(1 / (N * log(2)))`, which approaches `1` as `N` tends to infinity.

Given this absolute bound on compression ratio, any approach you can find which is reasonably efficient is worth going for; for values as small as N = 15 it's impossible to do better than 90%.

Answer (score 2):

Currently you are using N*2^N bits.

Basically what you have is a permutation of the numbers, and each permutation is unique, and for permutation you can calculate a unique identifier. Since there are (2^N)! permutations, you will only need ceil(log2((2^N)!)) bits. For you example, this is 45 bits.