# Arrangement of n objects (Permutation with duplicates)

Tags: algorithm, math, combinatorics

I am looking for a fast implementation of the "arrangement" algorithm (permutation with duplicates). 
Given N objects (A in quantity a, B in quantity b, ...), generate all the possible combinations.
Exemple:

```
Arrangement("AAA", "B", "CC") would return :   
"AAABCC" "AABACC" "AABCAC" "AABCCA" "ABAACC" "ABACAC" "ABACCA" "ABCAAC"   
"ABCACA" "ABCCAA" "BAAACC" "BAACAC" "BAACCA" "BACAAC" "BACACA" "BACCAA"   
"BCAAAC" "BCAACA" "BCACAA" "BCCAAA" "AAACBC" "AACABC" "AACBAC" "AACBCA"   
"ACAABC" "ACABAC" "ACABCA" "ACBAAC" "ACBACA" "ACBCAA" "CAAABC" "CAABAC"   
"CAABCA" "CABAAC" "CABACA" "CABCAA" "CBAAAC" "CBAACA" "CBACAA" "CBCAAA"   
"AAACCB" "AACACB" "AACCAB" "AACCBA" "ACAACB" "ACACAB" "ACACBA" "ACCAAB"   
"ACCABA" "ACCBAA" "CAAACB" "CAACAB" "CAACBA" "CACAAB" "CACABA" "CACBAA"   
"CCAAAB" "CCAABA" "CCABAA" "CCBAAA"
```

(Code in C, C# or Pascal if possible)

Thanks in advance
Philippe

Comment: possible duplicate of [Permutations of a given set of numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653500/permutations-of-a-given-set-of-numbers) - there are several other related questions too

Comment: This function works when all objects are different.

Answer (score 6):

If you can use C++, it's already provided in the standard library:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() { 
    std::string a("AAABCC");

    do {
        std::cout << a << "\t";
    } while (std::next_permutation(a.begin(), a.end()));
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: the output from this is:

AAABCC  AAACBC  AAACCB  AABACC  AABCAC  AABCCA  AACABC  AACACB  AACBAC  AACBCA
AACCAB  AACCBA  ABAACC  ABACAC  ABACCA  ABCAAC  ABCACA  ABCCAA  ACAABC  ACAACB
ACABAC  ACABCA  ACACAB  ACACBA  ACBAAC  ACBACA  ACBCAA  ACCAAB  ACCABA  ACCBAA
BAAACC  BAACAC  BAACCA  BACAAC  BACACA  BACCAA  BCAAAC  BCAACA  BCACAA  BCCAAA
CAAABC  CAAACB  CAABAC  CAABCA  CAACAB  CAACBA  CABAAC  CABACA  CABCAA  CACAAB
CACABA  CACBAA  CBAAAC  CBAACA  CBACAA  CBCAAA  CCAAAB  CCAABA  CCABAA  CCBAAA

For anybody who can't use C++, Mark Nelson wrote an [article](http://marknelson.us/2002/03/01/next-permutation/) in the C/C++ User's Journal a few years ago that might be helpful.

Comment: @PhilippeC: perhaps the link I've added to the answer will be helpful.

Comment: Hi Jerry: thanks for the link. I had this function in my tools but never realized it worked with duplicates ...