# What is the best way to find all combinations of items in an array?

Tags: c#, algorithm

What is the best way to find all combinations of items in an array in C#?

Comment: do you mean "unique items in the array" or "all the different ways of ordering the items in your array"?

Comment: All the different ways of ordering the items in the array.

Comment: This is also know as the ´permutation´ of items within the array

Comment: See also: https://ericlippert.com/2013/04/15/producing-permutations-part-one/

Comment: @JorgeE.Hernández no, that's a _permutation_ not a _combination_

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is O(n!)

```
static List<List<int>> comb;
static bool[] used;
static void GetCombinationSample()
{
    int[] arr = { 10, 50, 3, 1, 2 };
    used = new bool[arr.Length];
    used.Fill(false);
    comb = new List<List<int>>();
    List<int> c = new List<int>();
    GetComb(arr, 0, c);
    foreach (var item in comb)
    {
        foreach (var x in item)
        {
            Console.Write(x + ",");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
}
static void GetComb(int[] arr, int colindex, List<int> c)
{

    if (colindex >= arr.Length)
    {
        comb.Add(new List<int>(c));
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!used[i])
        {
            used[i] = true;
            c.Add(arr[i]);
            GetComb(arr, colindex + 1, c);
            c.RemoveAt(c.Count - 1);
            used[i] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I'm with @gunr2171 here. I think readers of this post should not only copy-paste your code, they should also understand the algorithm logic behind it :)

Comment: What is that _Fill_ in  `used.Fill(false);` ?

Comment: @JackGriffin it fills every cell of the array with the value 'false'

Comment: @Thecave3 I think the question is, where `Fill` defined? It's not a member of `bool[]`, nor a Linq extension method. Regarless, however, `false` is the default value of `bool`, so it's not really needed in this case.

Comment: @JackGriffin `Array.Fill(used, false)`
you can see it's documentation here.
[Array.Fill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.fill?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 132):

**UPDATED**

Here are a set of generic functions (require .net 3.5 or higher) for different scenarios. The outputs are for a list of {1, 2, 3, 4} and a length of 2.

**Permutations with repetition**

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> 
    GetPermutationsWithRept<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, int length)
{
    if (length == 1) return list.Select(t => new T[] { t });
    return GetPermutationsWithRept(list, length - 1)
        .SelectMany(t => list, 
            (t1, t2) => t1.Concat(new T[] { t2 }));
}
```

Output:

```
{1,1} {1,2} {1,3} {1,4} {2,1} {2,2} {2,3} {2,4} {3,1} {3,2} {3,3} {3,4} {4,1} {4,2} {4,3} {4,4}
```

**Permutations**

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>
    GetPermutations<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, int length)
{
    if (length == 1) return list.Select(t => new T[] { t });
    return GetPermutations(list, length - 1)
        .SelectMany(t => list.Where(o => !t.Contains(o)),
            (t1, t2) => t1.Concat(new T[] { t2 }));
}
```

Output:

```
{1,2} {1,3} {1,4} {2,1} {2,3} {2,4} {3,1} {3,2} {3,4} {4,1} {4,2} {4,3}
```

**K-combinations with repetition**

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> 
    GetKCombsWithRept<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, int length) where T : IComparable
{
    if (length == 1) return list.Select(t => new T[] { t });
    return GetKCombsWithRept(list, length - 1)
        .SelectMany(t => list.Where(o => o.CompareTo(t.Last()) >= 0), 
            (t1, t2) => t1.Concat(new T[] { t2 }));
}
```

Output:

```
{1,1} {1,2} {1,3} {1,4} {2,2} {2,3} {2,4} {3,3} {3,4} {4,4}
```

**K-combinations**

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> 
    GetKCombs<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, int length) where T : IComparable
{
    if (length == 1) return list.Select(t => new T[] { t });
    return GetKCombs(list, length - 1)
        .SelectMany(t => list.Where(o => o.CompareTo(t.Last()) > 0), 
            (t1, t2) => t1.Concat(new T[] { t2 }));
}
```

Output:

```
{1,2} {1,3} {1,4} {2,3} {2,4} {3,4}
```

Comment: good approach but it doesn't work with `GetKCombs( new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, 3);`

Comment: Permutations failed if IEnumerable parameter contains same string 2times.

Comment: K-combinations fail with strings, presumably a problem with _CompareTo()_ :    
`source = { aa, bb, cc }, length = 2 : { aa bb }, { aa cc }, { bb cc }´ [correct]   
 `source = { big, red, car }, length = 2 : { big red }, { big car }, { car red }´-> [incorrect : should be : { red car}]

Comment: @Pengyang would there be an easy way to start `GetPermutations` at a specified index? Using .Skip() to restore a previously iterated permutation can take a long time. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

That's called permutations.

This can give you the permutations of any collection:

```
public class Permutation {

  public static IEnumerable<T[]> GetPermutations<T>(T[] items) {
    int[] work = new int[items.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < work.Length; i++) {
      work[i] = i;
    }
    foreach (int[] index in GetIntPermutations(work, 0, work.Length)) {
      T[] result = new T[index.Length];
      for (int i = 0; i < index.Length; i++) result[i] = items[index[i]];
      yield return result;
    }
  }

  public static IEnumerable<int[]> GetIntPermutations(int[] index, int offset, int len) {
    if (len == 1) {
      yield return index;
    } else if (len == 2) {
      yield return index;
      Swap(index, offset, offset + 1);
      yield return index;
      Swap(index, offset, offset + 1);
    } else {
      foreach (int[] result in GetIntPermutations(index, offset + 1, len - 1)) {
        yield return result;
      }
      for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        Swap(index, offset, offset + i);
        foreach (int[] result in GetIntPermutations(index, offset + 1, len - 1)) {
          yield return result;
        }
        Swap(index, offset, offset + i);
      }
    }
  }

  private static void Swap(int[] index, int offset1, int offset2) {
    int temp = index[offset1];
    index[offset1] = index[offset2];
    index[offset2] = temp;
  }

}
```

Example:

```
string[] items = { "one", "two", "three" };
foreach (string[] permutation in Permutation.GetPermutations<string>(items)) {
  Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", permutation));
}
```

Comment: I think there is difference between permutation and combination

Comment: @Ahmed: "All the different ways of ordering the items" is clearly permutations. If your code is doing something different, then it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: How can i use the above class for this type of collection     float[,] permutations = new float[90,600];                                 It would be really helpful if you can you explain with an example.

Comment: @RAZER: You would have to flatten it to a single dimension array, however the number of permutations would be collossal. I can't even calculate it. Just 3000 items would give 4.15e+9130 permutations...

Comment: Oh sorry the declaration is like this                      List<int[]> image_matrix = new List<int[]>();                          So i guess only 90 permutations.

Comment: Just use `ToArray` to create an array from the list. If you have 90 items in the list, it's about 1,49e+138 permutations.

Answer (score 6):

Regarding Pengyang answer:
Here is my generic function which can return all the combinations from a list of T:

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>
    GetCombinations<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, int length)
{
    if (length == 1) return list.Select(t => new T[] { t });

    return GetCombinations(list, length - 1)
        .SelectMany(t => list, (t1, t2) => t1.Concat(new T[] { t2 }));
}
```

Example 1:n=3,k=2

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> result =
    GetCombinations(Enumerable.Range(1, 3), 2);
```

Output - a list of integer-lists:

```
{1, 1} {1, 2} {1, 3} {2, 1} {2, 2} {2, 3} {3, 1} {3, 2} {3, 3}
```

.............................................................................

I ran this example and I am not quite sure about the rightness of the results.

Example 2:n=3, k=3

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> result =
    GetCombinations(Enumerable.Range(1, 3), 3);
```

Output - a list of integer-lists:

```
{1, 1, 1} {1, 1, 2} {1, 1, 3} 
{1, 2, 1} {1, 2, 2} {1, 2, 3} 
{1, 3, 1} {1, 3, 2} {1, 3, 3}
{2, 1, 1} {2, 1, 2} {2, 1, 3} 
{2, 2, 1} {2, 2, 2} {2, 2, 3} 
{2, 3, 1} {2, 3, 2} {2, 3, 3}
{3, 1, 1} {3, 1, 2} {3, 1, 3} 
{3, 2, 1} {3, 2, 2} {3, 2, 3} 
{3, 3, 1} {3, 3, 2} {3, 3, 3}
```

This should not happen with combinations otherwise it should specify it is with repetition.See article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinations

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've updated my answer with more solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [kwcombinatorics](http://kwcombinatorics.codeplex.com/) can provide some assistance (see example on home page):

> The KwCombinatorics library are 3 classes that provide 3 different ways of generating ordered (ranked) lists of combinations of numbers. These combinatorics are useful for software testing, allowing the generation of various types of possible combinations of input. Other uses include solving mathematical problems and games of chance.

Answer (score 2):

There are couples of very easy way to find the combination of string input by user.

> First way by using LINQ

```
private static IEnumerable<string> FindPermutations(string set)
        {
            var output = new List<string>();
            switch (set.Length)
            {
                case 1:
                    output.Add(set);
                    break;
                default:
                    output.AddRange(from c in set let tail = set.Remove(set.IndexOf(c), 1) from tailPerms in FindPermutations(tail) select c + tailPerms);
                    break;
            }
            return output;
        }
```

***Use this function like***

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a sting ");

            var input = Console.ReadLine();

            foreach (var stringCombination in FindPermutations(input))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(stringCombination);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

> Other way is to use loop

```
// 1. remove first char 
    // 2. find permutations of the rest of chars
    // 3. Attach the first char to each of those permutations.
    //     3.1  for each permutation, move firstChar in all indexes to produce even more permutations.
    // 4. Return list of possible permutations.
    public static string[] FindPermutationsSet(string word)
    {
        if (word.Length == 2)
        {
            var c = word.ToCharArray();
            var s = new string(new char[] { c[1], c[0] });
            return new string[]
            {
                word,
                s
            };
        }
        var result = new List<string>();
        var subsetPermutations = (string[])FindPermutationsSet(word.Substring(1));
        var firstChar = word[0];
        foreach (var temp in subsetPermutations.Select(s => firstChar.ToString() + s).Where(temp => temp != null).Where(temp => temp != null))
        {
            result.Add(temp);
            var chars = temp.ToCharArray();
            for (var i = 0; i < temp.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                var t = chars[i];
                chars[i] = chars[i + 1];
                chars[i + 1] = t;
                var s2 = new string(chars);
                result.Add(s2);
            }
        }
        return result.ToArray();
    }
```

> you can use this function like

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a sting ");

        var input = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Here is all the possable combination ");
        foreach (var stringCombination in FindPermutationsSet(input))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(stringCombination);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

For detailed answer see: Donald Knuth, The Art of computer programming (aka TAOCP). Volume 4A, Enumeration and Backtracking, chapter 7.2. Generating all possibilities. 
http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/taocp.html

Answer (score 1):

Another version of the solution given by Gufa. Below the complete source code of the class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Permutation
    {

        public IEnumerable<T[]> GetPermutations<T>(T[] items)
        {
            var work = new int[items.Length];
            for (var i = 0; i < work.Length; i++)
            {
                work[i] = i;
            }
            foreach (var index in GetIntPermutations(work, 0, work.Length))
            {
                var result = new T[index.Length];
                for (var i = 0; i < index.Length; i++) result[i] = items[index[i]];
                yield return result;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<int[]> GetIntPermutations(int[] index, int offset, int len)
        {
            switch (len)
            {
                case 1:
                    yield return index;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    yield return index;
                    Swap(index, offset, offset + 1);
                    yield return index;
                    Swap(index, offset, offset + 1);
                    break;
                default:
                    foreach (var result in GetIntPermutations(index, offset + 1, len - 1))
                    {
                        yield return result;
                    }
                    for (var i = 1; i < len; i++)
                    {
                        Swap(index, offset, offset + i);
                        foreach (var result in GetIntPermutations(index, offset + 1, len - 1))
                        {
                            yield return result;
                        }
                        Swap(index, offset, offset + i);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        private static void Swap(IList<int> index, int offset1, int offset2)
        {
            var temp = index[offset1];
            index[offset1] = index[offset2];
            index[offset2] = temp;
        }

    }
}
```

This actually worked as it should for combinations.But is does not allow to chose combinations of n in k ...

Answer (score 1):

How about some recursion?

```
internal HashSet<string> GetAllPermutations(IEnumerable<int> numbers)
{
  HashSet<string> results = new HashSet<string>();

  if (numbers.Count() > 0)
    results.Add(string.Join(",", new SortedSet<int>(numbers)));

  for (int i = 0; i <= numbers.Count() - 1; i++)
  {
    List<int> newNumbers = new List<int>(numbers);
    newNumbers.RemoveAt(i);
    results.UnionWith(GetAllPermutations(newNumbers));
  }

  return results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a method to get the unique combination of all the integer elements in an array as shown below. I've used `Tuple` to represent a pair or combination of numbers:

```
private static void CombinationsOfItemsInAnArray()    
{
        int[] arr = { 10, 50, 3, 1, 2 }; //unique elements

        var numberSet = new HashSet<int>();
        var combinationList = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
        foreach (var number in arr)
        {
            if (!numberSet.Contains(number))
            {
                //create all tuple combinations for the current number against all the existing number in the number set
                foreach (var item in numberSet)
                    combinationList.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(number, item));

                numberSet.Add(number);
            }
        }

        foreach (var item in combinationList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{{{0}}} - {{{1}}}",item.Item1,item.Item2);
        }
    }
```

When I invoke this method in a console application then I get below output:

```
{50} - {10}
{3} - {10}
{3} - {50}
{1} - {10}
{1} - {50}
{1} - {3}
{2} - {10}
{2} - {50}
{2} - {3}
{2} - {1}
```

Answer (score 0):

`permutations with repetitions`, but iterative (not recursive).
It uses an array with all current indexes, and increments them as if they were the digits of a number :

```
/// <summary>
/// Generates combinations with repetitions
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Type of items to combine.</typeparam>
/// <param name="items">Array of items. Will not be modified.</param>
/// <param name="length">Length of combinations, equal to <paramref name="items"/> length if null</param>
/// <param name="reverse">If changes should begin with array end (high indexes) first</param>
/// <returns>Combinations of input items.</returns>
public static IEnumerable<T[]> Combinations<T>(this T[] items, int? length = null, bool reverse = true)
{
    var itemsLength = items.Length;
    var combinationLength = length ?? itemsLength;
    var indexes = new int[combinationLength];

    var overflow = false;
    while (!overflow)
    {
        var combination = new T[combinationLength];
        for (var i = 0; i < combinationLength; i++)
            combination[i] = items[indexes[reverse ? combinationLength - i - 1 : i]];
        yield return combination;

        overflow = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < combinationLength && overflow; i++)
        {
            var index = indexes[i] + 1;
            overflow = index == itemsLength;
            indexes[i] = overflow ? 0 : index;
        }
    }
}
```

Output for `new[] { 1, 2, 3}.Combinations(2, true)` :

```
{1,1} {1,2} {1,3} {2,1} {2,2} {2,3} {3,1} {3,2} {3,3}
```

Output for `new[] { 1, 2, 3}.Combinations(2, false)` :

```
{1,1} {2,1} {3,1} {1,2} {2,2} {3,2} {1,3} {2,3} {3,3}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Linq;    

string[] cols = new[] { "A", "B", "C" };
string[] rows = new[] { "1", "2", "3" };

var combinations = cols.SelectMany(col => rows, (col, row) => $"{col}{row}").ToList();

foreach(var entry in combinations )
    Console.WriteLine(entry);
// Output: A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3 C1 C2 C3
```