# C# ArrayList Combinations

Tags: c#

```
static IEnumerable<string> GetCombinations(string s, int length) 
{
    if (length > s.Length || length == 0)
    {
        return new[] { String.Empty };
        if (length == 1)
        {
            return s.Select(c => new string(new[] { c }));
        }
    }
    return from c in s
    from combination in GetCombinations(
      s.Remove(s.IndexOf(c), 1),
      length - 1
    )
    select c + combination;
}
```

This code work in strings.But I want ArrayList Combinations..For Example,

```
Arraylist.add('a,b');
Arraylist.add('a,c');
Arraylist.add('f,g');
Arraylist.add('h,l');
```

for length=3

```
'a,b,c','a,b,f','a,b,g'........
```

I'm sorry I'm new to C #..
Very even though I tried I could not..
Do you have an idea for this?

Comment: Are you looking for [generic methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/twcad0zb(v=vs.100).aspx)?

Comment: For starters you should be using the generic `List<T>` instead of `ArrayList`

Comment: Are you trying to calclulate all combinations of 2 lists?

Comment: Yes,I calculate it with other function..

Comment: Hey! That's [my code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174926/how-to-get-all-combination-of-an-arraylist/4174954#4174954)!

Comment: perhaps before copying @Jasons code verbatim you should take the time to understand how it works, you may be able to figure it out if you do that.

Comment: Yes u are right jason...I have not said already doing my own code..