# How to filter a List of int list with condition?

Tags: c#

I have this `List<List<int>>`:

```
{{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{2,3},{2,4},{3,4}}
```

In this list there are 6 list, which contain numbers from 1 to 4, and the occurrence of each number is 3;

I want to filter it in order to get:

```
{{1,2}{1,3}{2,4}{3,4}}
```

here the occurrence of each number is 2;

the lists are generated dynamically and I want to be able to filter also dynamically, base on the occurrence;

**Edit-More Details**

I need to count how many times a number is contain in the `List<List<int>>`, for the above example is 3. Then I want to exclude lists from the `List<List<int>>` in order to reduce the number of times from 3 to 2, 
The main issue for me was to find a way to not block my computer :), and also to get each number appear for 2 times (mandatory);

Comment: Could you add more details about which tuples you want to ommit? It's not really clear (to me) what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sounds like something straight out from [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net) :-) I like it!

Comment: @RenéVogt He wants to remove those tuples, which when removed would result in all individual numbers occurring a certain amount of times, e.g. 2

Comment: @GediminasMasaitis I understood that so far. I just wanted to know if Will Harrison's pseudo code is a correct approach or if there are tuples that should be preferred over others for the result set.

Comment: @GediminasMasaitis In Will Harrison's answer, {2,3} would be added to the result and the last tuples would therefor be skipped. If OP really wants the result he showed instead, I think this question is off-topic or too broad for SO. (http://xkcd.com/1425/)

Comment: Is it guaranteed that there is always a solution?

Comment: @displayName - Yes, every time the number of times that an item appear in lists is the same for all items

Comment: what is the rule for it to skip the element {2,3} ? and why should it return {2,4} ? because both 2 and 3 have been returned only once

Comment: in order to have all numbers in lists with  occurrence of 2, we need to skip some lists , other wise not all numbers will have occurrence 2;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if it's always a combination of 2 numbers, and they have to appear N times on the list, it means that depending on the N You gonna have:

4 (different digits) x 2 (times hey have to appear) = 8 digits = 4 pairs

4 x 3 (times) = 12 = 6 (pairs)

4 x 4 = 16 = 8 pairs

That means - that from 6 pairs we know we must select 4 pairs that best match the criteria

so based on the basic combinatorics (https://www.khanacademy.org/math/probability/probability-and-combinatorics-topic/permutations/v/permutation-formula)
we have a 6!/2! = (6*5*4*3*2*1)/(2*1)= 360 possible permutations

basically You can have 360 different ways how You put the the second list together.

because it doesn't matter how You arrange the items in the list (the order of items in the list) then the number of possible combinations is 6!/(2!*4!) = 15
https://www.khanacademy.org/math/probability/probability-and-combinatorics-topic/combinations-combinatorics/v/combination-formula

so the thing is - you have 15 possible answers to Your question.
Which means - you only need to loop over it for 15 times.
There are only 15 ways to chose 4 items out of the list of 6

seems like this is a solution to Your - "killing the machine" question.

so next question - how do we find all the possible 'combination'
Let's define all the possible items that we can pick from the input array
for example 1-st, 2-nd, 3-rd and 4-th..

> 1,2,3,4.......   1,2,3,5......     1,2,3,6 ...

All the combinations would be (from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10629938/444149)

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>  GetKCombs<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, int length) where T : IComparable
    {
        if (length == 1) return list.Select(t => new T[] { t });
        return GetKCombs(list, length - 1)
            .SelectMany(t => list.Where(o => o.CompareTo(t.Last()) > 0),
                (t1, t2) => t1.Concat(new T[] { t2 }));
    }
```

and invoke with (because there are 6 items to pick from, who's indexed are 0,1,2,3,4 and 5)

```
 var possiblePicks = GetKCombs(new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, 4);
```

we get 15 possible combinations
so now - we try taking 4 elements out of the first list, and check if they match the criteria.. if not.. then take another combination

```
 var data = new List<List<int>>
            {
                new List<int> { 1,2 },
                new List<int> { 1,3 },
                new List<int> { 1,4 },
                new List<int> { 2,3 },
                new List<int> { 2,4 },
                new List<int> { 3,4 }
            };


  foreach (var picks in possiblePicks)
            {
                var listToTest = new List<List<int>>(4);
                foreach (var i in picks)
                    listToTest.Add(data[i]);

                var ok = Check(listToTest, 2);
                if (ok)
                    break;
            }



  private bool Check(List<List<int>> listToTest, int limit)
        {
            Dictionary<int, int> ret = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            foreach (var inputElem in listToTest)
            {
                foreach (var z in inputElem)
                {
                    var returnCount = ret.ContainsKey(z) ? ret[z] : 0;
                    if (!ret.ContainsKey(z))
                        ret.Add(z, returnCount + 1);
                    else
                        ret[z]++;
                }

            }
            return ret.All(p => p.Value == limit);
        }
```

I'm sure this can be further optimized to minimize the amount of iterations other the 'listToTest'

Also, this is a lazy implementation (Ienumerable) - so if it so happens that the very first (or second) combination is successful, it stop iterating.

Comment: Marty, listToTest.Add(data[i]); ->here data[i] is the list from my example?

Comment: Yes, it is the source data

Answer (score 0):

I accepted the Marty's answer because fixed my issue, any way trying to use his method for larger lists, I found my self blocking again my computer so I start looking for another method and I end it up with this one:

```
var main = new List<HashSet<int>> {
            new HashSet<int> {1,2},
            new HashSet<int> {1,3},
            new HashSet<int> {1,4},
            new HashSet<int> {2,3},
            new HashSet<int> {2,4},
            new HashSet<int> {3,4} };


        var items = new HashSet<int>(from l in main from p in l select p); //=>{1,2,3,4}


        for (int i =main.Count-1;i-->0; )
        {               
            var occurence=items.Select(a=> main.Where(x => x.Contains(a)).Count()).ToList();
            var occurenceSum = 0;
            foreach(var j in main[i])
            {
                occurenceSum += occurence[j - 1];
                if (occurenceSum==6) //if both items have occurence=3, then the sum=6, then I can remove that list!
                {
                    main.RemoveAt(i);

                }
            }             

        }
```