# Second lambda in SelectMany

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Was curiouis and looked around for a LINQ permutation solution and found one here:

[What is the best way to find all combinations of items in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952153/what-is-the-best-way-to-find-all-combinations-of-items-in-an-array/10629938#10629938)

Here is the code in question:

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetPermutations<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, int length)
{
    if (length == 1) return list.Select(t => new T[] { t });
    return GetPermutations(list, length - 1)
      .SelectMany(t => list.Where(o => !t.Contains(o)),
        (t1, t2) => t1.Concat(new T[] { t2 }));
}
```

I understand the solution for the most part, but am unsure what `t1` and `t2` refer to in the SelectMany. I know `t1` is a Enumerable and `t2` is a T. Any explanations would be great, thanks!

Edit*

Oops, I was looking at the wrong SelectMany docs. The correct one signature is here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534631(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: What did you find in the documentation for `SelectMany` and how did it fail to answer your question?

Comment: I read the msdn docs for `SelectMany` at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx but the examples are pretty simple and I understand those. To clarify, I understand SelectMany is used to flatten collections, but after the flattening, what does t1, t2 refer to?

Comment: You're looking at the wrong documentation. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534631(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That would do it, makes much more sense now. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That second lambda is the [`resultSelector`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534631(v=vs.110).aspx) and allows for modifications of the selected collection (`t2`) depending on the instance that owns the collection (`t1`).

In your specific example `t1` is a permutation of `list` and `t2` is an element of all the elements from `list` that are not part of `t1`.

Hence `(t1, t2) => t1.Concat(new T[] { t2 })` is used to yield the next "generation" of permutations from a given permutation `t1` and the so far unused elements from `list`.

### Example:

Let `list` be `{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }` and let `t1` be `{ 1, 2 }`.

Then the `collectionSelector` will select all elements from `list` not inside `t1`, i.e. `{ 3, 4 }`, and the `resultSelector` will append each of those elements to `t1` once.

Thus yielding the permutations `{ 1, 2, 3 }` and `{ 1, 2, 4 }`.