# How can i get ALL combination of different TUPLES of n-elements from a list of objects?

Tags: c#, algorithm, permutation

I have a list of N players (let's say, 14 players - 1 to 14 numbers in the examples).

I want to obtain a Collection of ALL possible TUPLE of Y teams made by X players. **There can be players left out**, of course.

Input example: N = 14 players, Y = 3 teams, each composed by X = 3 players.
That means 14 players, split into 3 teams of 3 players. I want all the possibilities.

1) [123],[456],[789]         10,11,12,13,14 left out.

2) [456],[789],[10,11,12]    1,2,3,13,14    left out.
3) ....

I already looked into this post, which helped me to obtain all possible teams of X players, which i think might help me to reach my goal:
[What is the best way to find all combinations of items in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952153/what-is-the-best-way-to-find-all-combinations-of-items-in-an-array)
Now that i have all possible teams of X players, i need to get a step further. When i'll have all the possible tuple of teams, i will select which combination best suits my needs sorting them. Can you guys help me?
C# code would be great but even pseudocode can help.

Comment: I am not clear what you are asking for help with. Perhaps if you provided some code and pointed out where you need what exact outcome.

Comment: Note your sample problem has 7,971,964 possible team sets.

Comment: @JohnWu i wrote it down as better as i could, my english is not top notch i am afraid. But i got the answer i needed already, so it's fine!

Comment: @JohnWu I found it very clear. Too many questions being closed as unclear these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want combinations, not permuatations. Permutations means the order of players matters.

Using an extension method you can generate the combinations:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, int k) {
    return k == 0 ? new[] { new T[0] } :
      elements.SelectMany((e, i) =>
        elements.Skip(i + 1).Combinations(k - 1).Select(c => (new[] { e }).Concat(c)));
}
```

So, for your sample problem, setup the parameters:

```
var N = 14;
var NumTeams = 3;
var NumPlayersPerTeam = 3;
```

First you can generate all the players:

```
var players = Enumerable.Range(1, N);
```

Then you can get every possible team, by combining the players `NumPlayersPerTeam` at a time:

```
var AllTeams = players.Combinations(NumPlayersPerTeam);
```

Then you can get all the sets of teams, by combining the teams `NumTeams` at a time:

```
var PossibleTeamSets = AllTeams.Combinations(NumTeams);
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what i needed, glad you understood immediately. Your suggestion was correct and elegant but also so simple i felt a bit stupid after reading it. Thanks a lot, this was really helpful.