# combinations from 1 to n array and fill datagridview C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

**EDIT**

I need to fill a datagridview with all possible combinations of an array of 5 numbers which has range from 1 to n. (n lets say 100). My datagrid columns are Number1, Number2 Number3, Number4, Number 5.

I have read this
[What is the best way to find all combinations of items in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952153/what-is-the-best-way-to-find-all-combinations-of-items-in-an-array)

but I need to do the calculation on a button click and then fill the datagridview. Is that possible? thank you!

Comment: The answer is yes. Perhaps you need to ask for more detail?

Comment: Yes you are right...I need some help actually with tha math type...thank you

Comment: You array contains only distinct numbers?

Comment: Start with an array of 5 numbers. In a for-loop extract one number and return the remaining (`array.Except(new [] { x }).ToArray())` numbers. Recurse until you have an empty array.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to fill datagridview  is just by binding it to a dataTable...
so if you know how to do the math...
and if you know how to trigger a button click event...
just build a dataTable with all the columns and rows you need and when it's ready..
just do MyDataGridView.DataSource=MyDataTable...