# Combine values from same column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following structure:

```
Type    Value
A       abc
A       def
A       xyz
```

I want a result set that will be all possible combinations of the "Value" but should be distinct as well.

Result Set:

```
Value
abc def
abc xyz
def xyz
abc def xyz
```

If the result set has "abc def", I don't want "def abc" to show up. Even though these are 2 distinct values, these are duplicates for me. I'm stuck on 2 things:

1. How to eliminate duplicates?
2. In the table structure above, I had one type "A" with 3 values. The same table will have multiple types and each type will have different number of values. For instance, I will have Type "B" with say 4 values. How do I figure out how many times I need to iterate through each type.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  This logic requires hierarchical queries or recursive CTEs, which are not fully standardized across databases.  Plus, a query returns a fixed set of columns, so you can only get the combinations as a single string or array, not as different columns (unless you know the maximum number up-front).

Comment: Plus. if you're using a procedural language on the front-end, you might find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952153/what-is-the-best-way-to-find-all-combinations-of-items-in-an-array) helpful in generating all possible combinations from a set of values (see the highest voted answer). Just fetch your sets from the DB and then do combinatorics on the front-end.

Comment: We are using microsoft sql server. I want the result set to be multiple rows of the same column. There is no front-end for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this following query-

```
WITH CTE (id,Value)
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 1,Value 
    FROM your_table 
)


SELECT A.Value + ' '+ B.Value  AS Value
FROM CTE A 
INNER JOIN CTE B ON A.id = B.id
WHERE (A.Value <> B.Value AND A.Value > B.Value) 

UNION ALL

SELECT A.Value + ' '+ B.Value  + ' '  + C.Value AS Value
FROM CTE A 
INNER JOIN CTE B ON A.id = B.id
INNER JOIN CTE C ON A.id = C.id
WHERE 
(
    A.Value  <>B.Value AND A.Value  >B.Value 
    AND A.Value <> C.Value AND  A.Value > C.Value 
    AND B.Value <> C.Value AND B.Value > C.Value
)
```