# javascript return all combination of a number

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get all combination of a number. For example, input "123" should return `["123", "231", "213", "312", "321", "132"]`.

Here is my function:

```
function swapDigits(input) {
    for (var i = 0; i++; i < input.length - 1) {
        var output = [];
        var inter = input.slice(i, i + 1);
        var left = (input.slice(0, i) + input.slice(i + 1, input)).split("");
        for (var j = 0; j++; j <= left.length) {
            var result = left.splice(j, 0, inter).join("");
            output.push(result);

        }
    }
    console.log(output);
    return output;
}
```

However this function returns `undefined`, could anyone tell me what's going wrong?

Comment: When asking for help, format your code readably. It's basic courtesy. (It also, in this case, makes at least one of the errors more obvious.) I've done it for you on this occasion.

Comment: @crowder, take a closer look :)

Comment: For starters, output is not declared in the right spot. Move it outside the for loop.

Comment: It is 3! = 3 x 2 x 1 = 6 - if you refer to his code  or his example :) he has all the possible in his example.  In his code, well of course not :)

Comment: @alexmac: Ah, the OP isn't allowing the same digit twice.

Comment: Given that you already know how to use `console.log()`, did you try including some `console.log()` statements inside the outer and inner loops? That would make it obvious that the outer loop is executing zero times, which would in turn make it obvious why `output` doesn't get initialised to any particular value and thus remains `undefined`...

Comment: No one notice his for loop is wrong? Folks are picking on the guy for his formatting etc and no one notices  the for loop ? :) ' for (var i = 0; i++; i < input.length - 1)' which should be ' for (var i = 0; i < input.length - 1; i++)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors with the `for` loop and `scope` have already been mentioned. Besides that, the `splice` method will change the string that it operates on. This means that the inner loop will never terminate because `left` keeps on growing, so `j` never reaches `left.length`.

If you are new to a language, I would suggest starting with an implementation that is close to the algorithm that you want to implement. Then, once you are comfortable with it, use more advanced language constructs.

See **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acarlon/3Ku3f/5/)** for an example. This is the algorithm code:

```
function getPermutations(input)
{    
    if(input.length <= 1)
    {
        return [input];
    }
    var character = input[0];
    var returnArray = [];
    var subPermutes = getPermutations(input.slice(1));
    debugOutput('Returned array: ' + subPermutes);
    for(var subPermuteIndex = 0; subPermuteIndex < subPermutes.length; subPermuteIndex++ )
    {
       var subPermute = subPermutes[subPermuteIndex];
       for(var charIndex = 0; charIndex <= subPermute.length; charIndex++)
       {                         
           var pre = subPermute.slice( 0, charIndex );
           var post = subPermute.slice( charIndex );             
           returnArray.push(pre+character+post);           
           debugOutput(pre + '_' + character + '_' + post );
       }
    }
    return returnArray;
}
```

Basically, this will walk to the end of the string and work its way back constructing all permutations of sub-strings. It is easiest to see this from the debug output for `1234`. Note that 'Returned array' refers to the array that was created by the permutations of the sub-string. Also note that the current character is placed in every position in that array. The current character is shown between `_` such as the `1` in `432_1_`.

```
Returned array: 4
_3_4
4_3_
Returned array: 34,43
_2_34
3_2_4
34_2_
_2_43
4_2_3
43_2_
Returned array: 234,324,342,243,423,432
_1_234
2_1_34
23_1_4
234_1_
_1_324
3_1_24
32_1_4
324_1_
_1_342
3_1_42
34_1_2
342_1_
_1_243
2_1_43
24_1_3
243_1_
_1_423
4_1_23
42_1_3
423_1_
_1_432
4_1_32
43_1_2
432_1_
```

This algorithm doesn't enforce uniqueness. So, if you have a string `22` then you will get two results - `22,22`. Also, this algorithm uses recursion which I think is quite intuitive in this case, however there are pure iterative implementations [if you look for them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2799190/746754).

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in that code.

1. You have the order of the parts of the `for` statement incorrect. The order is *initialization*, *test*, *increment*. So `for (/* init */ ; /* test */ ; /* increment */)`
2. You're creating a new array for each iteration of your outer loop.

I'm making this a CW because I haven't checked for further errors than the above.