# Permutations in java

Tags: java

given a problem , a = (1,2,3) ,b= (A,B,C) ,c =(a1,b1,c1)

I want to get an output which prints me the value 1Aa1,1Ab1,1Ac1,1Ba1,1Bb1,1Bc1,1Ca1,1Cb1,1Cc1 Similarly with 2, with 3 then should start with A,B,C and then a1,b1,c1 .
The given output should print all the permutations and combinations  variables of the same .

I've already tried printing the same in for loop, it could only generate the combinations , Tried a few tutorials on printing the permutations

Can Someone please help me on that .

Comment: You need a recursive algorithm which uses backtracking.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799078/permutation-algorithm-without-recursion-java?lq=1)

Comment: is this what u want  : String a[] = {"1","2","3"};
  String b[] = {"A","B","C"};
  String c[] = {"a1","b1","c1"};
  
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
   for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
   {
    for(int k=0;k<3;k++)
    {
     System.out.println(a[i]+b[j]+c[k]);
    }
    
   }
  }

Answer (score 0):

Please try to post some code you have tried on your own.

For your reference I am giving a sample code and some explanation below:

The code uses recursion and is not optimized. It is just to give you an idea of how you could work with recursive problems. 
The function uses 4 args.

`Arg1` : is the String generated so far.

`Arg2` : is the array of Strings from which we can select a candidate to fill the next position.

`Arg3` : represents the positions filled up till now.

`Arg4` : is the length of permutation string, which will help us to determine we have reached the base case and we will just print the permutation and will not recurse further.

`Basic Thought Process`: The basic idea is that we will extract a character from the given arrays for every position and would form new String which would exclude that selected member and would pass this newly created set to further recurse.

```
class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String s[]= {"123","ABC","abc"};
        int len = 3; /* Length of the final permutation */
        permute ("", s, 0, len);
    }


    public static void permute (String soFar, String rest[], int pos, int len)
    {

        if (pos == len) {
            System.out.println (soFar);
        } else {

            for (int i = 0; i < rest[pos].length(); i++) {
                String remaining = rest[pos].substring(0, i) + rest[pos].substring(i+1);
                String newRest[] = new String[len];

                for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
                    newRest[j] = new String(rest[j]);
                }
                newRest[pos] = new String(remaining);

                permute (soFar + rest[pos].charAt(i), newRest, pos + 1, len);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Reference taken from: https://see.stanford.edu/materials/icspacs106b/h19-recbacktrackexamples.pdf

Output:

1Aa
1Ab
1Ac
1Ba
1Bb
1Bc
1Ca
1Cb
1Cc
2Aa
2Ab
2Ac
2Ba
2Bb
2Bc
2Ca
2Cb
2Cc
3Aa
3Ab
3Ac
3Ba
3Bb
3Bc
3Ca
3Cb
3Cc