# Adding ArrayList to HashSet in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, hashset

I was tasked with implementing a brute force algorithm to output all permutations of integers [1, 2, ..., n] for some n. However, I seem to have some problem with adding ArrayList objects to a HashSet:

```
static Set<List<Integer>> allPermutations(int n){
        if(n<=0){throw new IllegalArgumentException();}

        List<Integer> thisPermutation = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
            thisPermutation.add(i);
        }
        Set<List<Integer>> allPermutations = new HashSet<List<Integer>>();

        while(true){
            allPermutations.add(thisPermutation);
            thisPermutation = nextPermutation(thisPermutation);
            if(thisPermutation == null){break;}
        }
        return allPermutations;
}
```

I've discovered that the successive calls to 'nextPermutation' do indeed find all permutations, but I don't understand what happens when I add the permutations to the HashSet 'allPermutations'. The output I get on running with n=3 is this:

> [[3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1], [3, 2, 1, 1], [3, 2,
>   1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1], [3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1]]

I'm new to Java and would appreciate any help.

Edit: Here's the nextPermutation function:

```
static List<Integer> nextPermutation(List<Integer> sequence){
        int i = sequence.size() - 1;
        while(sequence.get(i) < sequence.get(i-1)){
            i -= 1;
            if(i == 0){
                return null;
            }
        }
        int j = i;
        while(j != sequence.size()-1 && sequence.get(j+1) > sequence.get(i-1)){
            j += 1;
        }
        int tempVal = sequence.get(i-1);
        sequence.set(i-1, sequence.get(j));
        sequence.set(j, tempVal);

        List<Integer> reversed = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int k = sequence.size()-1; k>=i; k--){
            reversed.add(sequence.get(k));
        }

        List<Integer> next = sequence.subList(0, i);
        next.addAll(reversed);

        return next;
}
```

Comment: seems problem with the `nextPermutation` implementation. share that function too

Comment: Can you share the `nextPermutation` method as well please.

Comment: [See this answer for similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478238/permutation-iterator-in-java/56736726#56736726)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List<Integer> sequence` is passed to the `nextPermutation` method and modified inside the method: `sequence.set(j, tempVal);`. Thus, the original permutation is modified each time the `nextPermutation` method is called ([Call by sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing)).

However, you could easily adapt your code to create a copy of the list inside the method:

```java
static List<Integer> nextPermutation(final List<Integer> s) {
    List<Integer> sequence = new ArrayList<>(s);
    int i = sequence.size() - 1; 
    // ...
}
```