# How do I create n amount of nested for loops in Java?

Tags: java

So I have a code which generates all possible strings of a length n (currently 5 in this example) with characters in a list "chars" and executes a certain code once on each string in the end (not included here).
How would I condense the code here into code that automatically nests the loops n amount of times and then executes a final code on each result?

```
            for(String str2: chars) {
            str2 = str1 + str2;
            for(String str3: chars) {
                str3 = str2 + str3;
                for(String str4: chars) {
                    str4 = str3 + str4;
                    for(String str5: chars) {
                        str5 = str4 + str5;
                        for(String str6: chars) {
                            str6 = str5 + str6;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: just use recursion. https://www.javatpoint.com/recursion-in-java#:~:text=Recursion%20in%20java%20is%20a,compact%20but%20complex%20to%20understand.

Comment: You should really look for better approach than this to generate all possible strings.

Comment: This is for a hashing algorithm, so it needs to go through them all.

Comment: It also cannot use recursion, as the variables in it need to be saved separately on each "level" of the nest

Comment: Basically a solved problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799078/permutation-algorithm-without-recursion-java for example.

Comment: "It also cannot use recursion" this doesn't preclude recursion, you just need a way to update the "variables", e.g. by storing them in a list.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use recursion

```
static void allCombinationsRecursive(String current, String symbols, int level) {
    if(level == 0)
        // no more nested loop
        System.out.println(current);
    else
        // current loop
        for(Character c: symbols.toCharArray())
            // next nested loops
            allCombinationsRecursive(current + c, symbols, level - 1);
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    allCombinationsRecursive("", "ABC", 2);
}
```

with output

```
AA
AB
AC
BA
BB
BC
CA
CB
CC
```

If you need an iterative version, you must carry out the state for every nested loop

```
static void allCombinationsIterative(String symbols, int levels) {
    // current index for each loop
    int [] index = new int [levels];   // << here any NESTED LEVEL STATE
    // not started
    for(int i = 0; i < levels; i++)
        index[i] = -1;
    // current level is 0
    int level = 0;
    while(level >= 0) {
        // max level reatched?
        if(level == levels) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.stream(index).mapToObj(i -> symbols.substring(i, i + 1)).collect(joining("")));
            level -= 1;
        } else {
            // can we inc this level?
            if (index[level] < symbols.length() - 1) {
                index[level] += 1;
                level += 1;
            } else {
                // back
                index[level] = -1;
                level -= 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(with the same output)

Note that neither algorithm takes into account what type of algorithm is involved (generating combinations or any other problem).