# Evaluate equality among n variables, without check each pair

Tags: c#

Not sure if this is possible somehow, without doing a full comparison between each of the N variables.

for int or float, I can use simple math, to figure out if the numbers are the same; doing the sum, and dividing by the number of elements.

But if I want to check if 3 variables contain the same string, I can't use this approach.
It may be possible that either var1 and var2 are the same, or that var3 and var 1 are the same, and also that var2 and var3 may be the same. From what I understand, unless you make a comparison among EACH variable, there is no way to know if the content of that variable is the same.

Did I miss something or there is an easier way?

Example with 3 variables:

```
string var1 = "hello";
string var2 = "there";
string var3 = "hello";

if (var1 == var2 || var1 == var3 || var2 == var3)
    //got a duplicate
else
    //all are different
```

Imagine to compare 20 variables, it takes forever to write a comparison statement.

To me it sound similar to a search algorithm, could I apply the same concept that I may apply to a sorted binary search?

Comment: Try adding them in a list

Comment: It does not matter if the sequences are the same; although I see the flaw in the math of doing the sum and then divide by the number of elements. 5,5,5 would give 15 and divided by 3 would match the first variable (5), but this would be the same if the sequence was 5,4,6; since it would divide by 3 and give 5, as the first case, but here we have no duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put them into a collection, then your life is much easier.

A subtle but efficient approach is using a `HashSet<>`:

```
string[] collection = { var1, var2, var3 };
var set = new HashSet<string>();
bool noDuplicate = collection.All(set.Add);
```

[`HashSet.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005(v=vs.110).aspx) returns `true` if the item could be added which is the case if it was not already there. So this collection doesn't allow duplicates. `Enumerable.All` will stop enumeration on the first `false`. If all are unique all can be added to the set and `noDuplicate` will be `true`.

Comment: This seems to be the best solution; it is quick, simple and not much code to write. Thanks

Comment: Won't this check if only the first element has duplicates?

Comment: @DovydasSopa: of course, so i've modified my answer :)

Comment: Does this work also if I create the set and assign the variables at instantiation time? Or do I have to use the .add method for each variable?

Comment: @newbiez: sorry, i can't quite follow.

Comment: Like you do with the string collection array; can I create a hashset of strings, and pass the varN as parameter when instantiating it?

var set = new HashSet<string>() { var1, var2, var3,...varN};

Comment: @newbiez: Yes, you can pass a collection to the constructor of `HashSet`. So another way would be to use `var set = new HashSet<string>(collection); bool noDuplicate=collection.Length==set.Count;`. But i like the LINQ approach more since it stops as soon as a duplicate was found.

Comment: Or do you ask if a `HashSet<T>` supports [collection initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) syntax? Yes, it does.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to create as less objects as possible; creating the set directy, instead than create an array of strings and a set, feel better space wise (in the long run of course; writing something scalable for both time and space efficiency)

Answer (score 1):

you may try something like this:

```
List<string> l = new List<string>() {"a", "b", "a"};
bool isDuplicate = l.GroupBy(i => i).Any(x => x.Count() > 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all elements to list and just compare if normal list elements counts is same as dinstict:

```
string var1 = "hello";
string var2 = "there";
string var3 = "hello";
string[] values = new [] { var1, var2, var3 };
if (values.Length != values.Distinct.Count()) {
    // Got a duplicate.
} else {
    // All are different.
}
```

Comment: Thanks; although in this way there are 2 operations: one to add to the list, another to search for each duplicate. Not sure how the distinct function works internally, but it seems that this would have complexity 2n

Comment: @newbiez It will be equivalent to the TimSchmelter's solution - http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,4ab583c7d8e84d6d.

Comment: @Eugene Podskal It's not totally equivalent. TimSchmelter's solution will stop on first duplicate found. This solution will need to go though all the items.

Comment: @DovydasSopa Yes, I meant that it won't be O(n*n), but amortised O(n). Internally it uses "Hash"Set, though it will have to iterate through all the items.

Answer (score 0):

```
    string var1 = "hello";
    string var2 = "there";
    string var3 = "hello";
    string var4 = "hello";
    string var5 = "there";
    string var6 = "hello";
    List<string> strings = new List<string>() { var1, var2, var3,var4,var5,var6 };
    var grouped = strings.GroupBy(x => x);
    Dictionary<string,int> stringAndCount = grouped.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
```

The string (key) is the content of the variable, and the int value is how many variables in your list that equals that string key.

```
Key: hello, Value: 4
Key: there, Value: 2
```

**EDIT:**

If you just want to know if there are duplicates:

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>() { var1, var2, var3,var4,var5,var6 };

bool hasDupes = strings.Count != (new HashSet<string>(strings)).Count;
```

Comment: Thanks. So you create a list first and then a dictionary? That may work but it is quite a lot of overhead, time wise and space wise

Comment: @newbiez it *will* work, haha. This is only if you want to know how many duplicates there are. If you don't really mind, a HashSet will do it.

Comment: @newbiez Also I'm not sure which part you are thinking as having overhead, but a [Dictionary is also a hash](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15042066/1685167) . Plus GroupBy implements IENumerable, and it loads lazily. I won't try to argue though since although I am concerned with more obvious overhead, C# is not like C where more simple techniques are more optimized space and time-wise, because of JIT / IL and stuff.

Comment: Yep, I am not really interested in how many duplicates I have; I need to know if there are duplicates only; and act accordingly :) I am looking at the scenario where the function that I call, is called multiple times in multiple instances; which cause 2 objects to be created every time...so I am trying to get a solution that generate less objects as possible; to be more efficient (I work with big numbers, so the struggle is real)

Comment: @newbiez edited my answer to something that might be more useful, although it's probably answered elsewhere in this page already (EDIT: A little more complex than Tim's answer :P)