# How to traverse through char array

Tags: c#, algorithm, traversal

Function receives char[,].

For example if it it takes

```
000
LAD
0B0
```

Traversing should print out all possible combinations of non-zero chars:

```
L
LA
LAD
LAB
A
AL
AB
AD
```

and so on

```
private void Traverse(char[,] area) 
{

}
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: This example may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756055/listing-all-permutations-of-a-string-integer

Comment: Combinations or Permutations? Order is important for permutations, but not so for combinations. And you want **all** such? Meaning if the set of letters is of length 5 ({a,b,c,d,e}), your going to want combinations of 5 things, taken 5 at a time, 4 at a time, 3 at a time, 2 at a time, 1 at a time? This question should start you on your way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to write a recursive function with two strings, initial and output. I assume you want combinations, not permutation so it's a little easier. The base case is checking if initial is empty, then print out the output. The step is removing a character from initial and calling the recursive function twice, one with the unchanged output and one with the removed character added into the output. If the removed character is 0, however, then you only call the function once (removing the 0 without adding anything to the output.)