# Get all possible combinations from a list of string

Tags: c#

I have the following array of strings:

```
var words = new List<string> { "Win", "Care", "q10", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun" };
```

I want to get all combinations from the array (use all words in each combination)

e.g.

1. WinCareq10MonTueWedThurFriSatSun
2. Monq10TueWedThurFriSatSunWinCare
3. CareSunMonWinTueWedThurFriSatq10
4. SunMonq10TueCareWedThurWinFriSat

**NOTE : In every combination, all words from list of string must be used.**

Comment: The OP is looking for permutations instead of combinations.

Comment: do you need permutations with repeats or without?

Comment: I want all words from list of string with all possible positions. Repetition of words is allowed.

Comment: Why does everybody ask WHY he want to do something instead of get him an answer?

Comment: @PaulZahra It was more a general problem of SO. Xanatos and David Arno aked - but WHY? Someone has a problem and is looking for a solution. There is no need to ask why when a solution is available. Only if no solution exists one should ask why. That's my opinion but this question is not the place to discuss it.

Comment: @Verarind While I understand how some might be frustrated by that kind of interaction... sometimes I find myself wondering if the 'asker' completely understands the problem at hand and whether a different solution would be 'better'... so sometimes asking 'WHY?' is pretty valid.

Comment: @Verarind, I often ask why because I think it a constructive thing to do at times. Here I asked it because I can't see the point to doing what the OP wants to do. The answer might then educate me. Other times, I want to check whether the OP is asking the "wrong" question. As explained by Paul, I might then be able to offer a far better answer a more general problem and teach better programming techniques along the way.

Comment: Try using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756055/listing-all-permutations-of-a-string-integer

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetPermutations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var itemAsEnumerable = Enumerable.Repeat(item, 1);
            var subSet = items.Except(itemAsEnumerable);
            if (!subSet.Any())
            {
                yield return itemAsEnumerable;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var sub in items.Except(itemAsEnumerable).GetPermutations())
                {
                    yield return itemAsEnumerable.Union(sub);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
var list = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" };
var permutations = list.GetPermutations();

var permutationsAsArray = permutations.Select(x => x.ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll need some of methods to permute an array of integers. F.e. you can try this:

```
public static IEnumerable<int[]> Permutations(int start, int count)
{
    if (count == 0)
        yield break;

    var array = Enumerable.Range(start, count)
                          .ToArray();

    if (count > 1)
    {
        do
            yield return array;
        while (NextPermutation(ref array));
    }
    else
        yield return array;
}

private static bool NextPermutation(ref int[] array)
{
    int k = array.Length - 2;
    while (k >= 0)
    {
        if (array[k] < array[k + 1])
            break;

        k--;
    }

    if (k < 0)
        return false;

    int l = array.Length - 1;
    while (l > k)
    {
        if (array[k] < array[l])
            break;

        l--;
    }

    int tmp = array[k];
    array[k] = array[l];
    array[l] = tmp;

    Array.Reverse(array, k + 1, array.Length - k - 1);

    return true;
}
```

This method looks complicated, but it's most efficient of existing methods.
Then you'll can use permutated integers as indices:

```
IReadOnlyList<string> words = ...
IEnumerable<int[]> permutations = Permutations(0, words.Length);
foreach (var permutation in permutations)
{
    var nextCase = new string[permutation.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < permutation.Length; i++)
       nextCase[i] = words[permutation[i]];

    var result = string.Join("", nextCase);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `ref` part of `NextPermutation`

Comment: @xanatos Yes, I don't need. It's just to demonstrate an `array` parameter is changeable.