# permutation with the word "password"

Tags: permutation

i need to "permutate" my name in all different ways possible, but don't know how.
It is for a console application written in C# and need to then save it in a dictionary.
Name is Jake.

looking for a output of:
JAKE
jake
JaKe
j@k3
J@KE
ect.

please help

Comment: You have to *explain the rules*. E.g. if `Jаke` (cyrillic `а`) is a valid permutation? What about `j_ke`? etc.

Comment: The only way that i found... "re-shuffles" the letters...  there must be a grouping way of keeping the letters in order? and just add different characters per place.  eg. {Jj}{aA@}{Kk}{eE3}

Comment: the only characters i can use is: jJ, aA@, kK, eE3

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this URL which answers similar kind of question. This provides the all permutations of a string/integer.

[Listing all permutations of a string/integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756055/listing-all-permutations-of-a-string-integer)