# Generate all possible strings of length l with n characters

Tags: string, algorithm, permutation

I want to generate all possible strings of a certain length l given n characters.

So for example if l = 2 and the characters are [a,b,c] the result should be:
'aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ba', 'bb','bc', 'ca', 'cb' and 'cc'.

Initially I had done this using a recursive algorithm that would do this. However, I get a lot of duplicates and it is very time consuming.

Moreover, I thought about an algorithm that would "count" in base n. So, in the example above if I replace a->0, b->1 and c->2 I am effectively counting to 'cc'-> 22 in base 3. However, this also strikes me as inefficient.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What language tho?

Comment: What do you mean, "I get a lot of duplicates"? "counting" in base N is exactly the usual non-recursive algorithm. You can see it in action in Python's source [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L2588), as the next item is evaluated by "incrementing" a tuple containing "digits".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listing all permutations of a string/integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756055/listing-all-permutations-of-a-string-integer)

Comment: This is exactly what I mean, however it does not support that the length of the string be longer than the size of the set of characters

Comment: @Amadan I know it, don't need to point it out. One of the tags is PERMUTATION so I provided a link.

Comment: Show us **YOUR** code. Use a debugger to find out why duplicates are generated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to implement any recoursion. All you have to do is to get the next item from previous one

```
 aa -> ab -> ac -> : we can't add 1 to c so why reset the last 'c' to 'a' 
                     but add 1 to previous 'a': 'ba'
                     now we keep on adding one to the last 'a':
 ba -> bb -> bc -> : again we reset 'c' to 'a' and increment previous b
 ca -> ...
```

**Code (C#)**; let's *generalize* the solution (any `alphabet` not necessary `string`)

```
// alphabet should contain distinct items
private static IEnumerable<T[]> Solution<T>(IEnumerable<T> alphabet, int length) {
  if (null == alphabet)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(alphabet));

  var chars = alphabet.Distinct().ToArray();

  if (length <= 0 || chars.Length <= 0)
    yield break;

  int[] result = new int[length];

  do {
    yield return result
      .Select(i => chars[i])
      .ToArray();

    for (int i = result.Length - 1; i >=0 ; --i)
      if (result[i] == chars.Length - 1) 
        result[i] = 0;
      else {
        result[i] += 1;
        break;
      }
  }
  while (!result.All(item => item == 0));
}
```

**Demo:**

```
// Or     var test = Solution("abc", 2);
var test = Solution(new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c' }, 2);

var report = string.Join(", ", test
  .Select(item => string.Concat(item)));
```

**Outcome:**

```
aa, ab, ac, ba, bb, bc, ca, cb, cc
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can represent "count base n" using division.

Alternative implementation - traverse all `n^m` values using approach like old electric counter wheels:

```
src = "abc";
n = len(src)
m = 2
l = [0]*m
i = 0
while i < m:
    print([src[x] for x in l])
    i = 0
    l[i] += 1
    while (i < m) and l[i] >= n:
        l[i] = 0
        i += 1
        if i < m:
            l[i] += 1

['a', 'a']
['b', 'a']
['c', 'a']
['a', 'b']
['b', 'b']
['c', 'b']
['a', 'c']
['b', 'c']
['c', 'c']
```

Comment: in python, you can use directly itertools.product(src, repeat=m). Moreover as it is a generator, there is no risk of memory overload.

Comment: @Vince You are right. I just wanted to show general approach (author didn't mention specific language)