# How to get all string "possibilities"

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, regex, string

Given a string like `string s = "a(b)cd(ef)"`,
what is the best way to get a list/array containing all the following strings:

```
"acd",
"abcd",
"acdef",
"abcdef"
```

Additional information:
The order of the result doesn't matter.
The amount of parenthesis is unknown

I have tried to do this with RegEx, but didn't get very far.

Comment: This is actually a fairly simple and fun problem. however your question is likely to be closed (probably wrongly) because it has shown no code or where you are stuck. Have you attempted anything?

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756055/listing-all-permutations-of-a-string-integer) might help you get started, although the answers probably don't consider optional parts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Listing all permutations of a string/integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756055/listing-all-permutations-of-a-string-integer)

Comment: I agree with downvotes, there are likely duplicates already around. But voting to close as "too broad" is definitely wrong. @MichaelRandall, it [should not be closed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/401157/1997232), but since OP mentined attempt and didn't show it, it could happen.

Comment: @John I didn't use the word "permutation" as I was under the impression that those were just about the order of elements.

Comment: Perhaps you're right there. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, however here is an example using a mask array to keep track of the permutation state, some regex, and a few helper methods

**Given**

```
// work out the states of the combination
public static bool GetNextState(bool[] states)
{
   for (var i = 0; i < states.Length; i++)
      if ((states[i] = !states[i]) == true)
         return false;
   return true;
}

// Create the combination
public static string Join(string[] split, string[] matches, bool[] states)
{
   var sb = new StringBuilder();
   for (var i = 0; i < states.Length; i++)
      sb.Append(split[i] + (states[i]? matches[i]:""));
   sb.Append(split.Last());
   return sb.ToString();
}

// enumerate the results
public static IEnumerable<string> Results(string input)
{
   var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"\(.+?\)")
         .Select(x => x.Value.Trim('(', ')'))
         .ToArray();
   var split = Regex.Split(input, @"\(.+?\)");
   var states = new bool[matches.Length];

   do {
      yield return Join(split, matches, states);
   } while (!GetNextState(states));
}
```

**Usage**

```
string s = "a(b)cd(ef)";

foreach (var result in Results(s))
   Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Output**

```
acd
abcd
acdef
abcdef
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aEya0A)

Answer (score 0):

Michael Randall's answer is correct, but after some more thinking I was finally able to come up with a (probably not very good) working solution as well

```
string s = "a(b)cd(ef)";
List<string> result = new List<string>();
int amount = s.Split('(').Length;
amount = (int)Math.Pow(2, amount - 1);

for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
{
    string temp = string.Copy(s);
    string binaryString = Convert.ToString(i, 2).PadLeft(amount, '0');
    string tempResult = "";

    for (int j = 0; j < binaryString.Length && !temp.Equals(""); j++)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"[^(]*");

        tempResult += regex.Match(temp).Value;

        if (binaryString[binaryString.Length - 1 - j].Equals('1'))
        {
            string regexStr = @"\(([^)]*)\)";
            regex = new Regex(regexStr);
            tempResult += regex.Match(temp).Value;
        }
        if (temp.Contains(')'))
            temp = temp.Substring(temp.IndexOf(')') + 1);
        else temp = "";
    }
    result.Add(tempResult.Replace("(", "").Replace(")", ""));
}
```